# View list of all JavaScript variables in Google Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Firebug, the DOM tab shows a list of all your public variables and objects. In Chrome's console you have to type the name of the public variable or object you want to explore.

Is there a way - or at least a command - for Chrome's console to display a list all the public variables and objects? It will save a lot of typing.

Answer (score 419, accepted):

Is this the kind of output you're looking for?

```
for(var b in window) { 
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) console.log(b); 
}
```

This will list everything available on the `window` object (all the functions and variables, e.g., `$` and `jQuery` on this page, etc.). Though, this is quite a list; not sure how helpful it is...

Otherwise just do `window` and start going down its tree:

```
window
```

This will give you `DOMWindow`, an expandable/explorable object.

Comment: DOMWindow doesn't have a `hasOwnProperty` method.

Comment: @ntownsend -My console disagrees with you :) [It's a property of `object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), why wouldn't it have it?

Comment: @Nick Craver - Withdrawn. When I posted the above comment, I did a test in my console that showed `window` had no `hasOwnProperty` method. Indeed, at that time, it didn't. I've just checked again, after reading your response, and my console now agrees that `window` has such a method. Mysterious.

Comment: "why wouldn't it have it?" The `[[Prototype]]` internal property of the global object is *implementation dependent*, in almost all major implementations -V8, Spidermonkey, Rhino, etc-, the global object inherits at some point from `Object.prototype`, but for example in other implementations -JScript, BESEN, DMDScript, etc...- it doesn't, so `window.hasOwnProperty` doesn't exist, to test it we can: `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(window);`

Comment: @CMS - Yes that's true...but the question is specifically about Chrome, so the implementation is known.

Comment: @CMS - Fair point, this is sure to come up in google for lots of other searches, +1 from me.

Comment: Or you could just type this;

Comment: This just saved me after about a day's worth of head banging....some global variable was defined in my user profile, and it kept stopping my js scripts. Was very frustrating

Comment: I wanted to see the value of the variable as well so i used: `for(var b in window) { 
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) console.log(b+" = "+window[b]); 
}`

Answer (score 82):

When script execution is halted (e.g., on a breakpoint) you can simply view all globals in the right pane of the Developer Tools window:

[image: chrome-globals]

Comment: can I spit out the vars from an execution context, like a break point show, without halting?

Comment: @MildFuzz Then use Nick Craver's solution (the accepted one).

Answer (score 79):

Open the console and then enter:

- `keys(window)` to see variables
- `dir(window)` to see objects

Comment: `dir(Function("return this")())` makes it work in Web Workers too

Comment: FYI ```dir(window)``` doesn't work in Firefox (yes I know this thread was about Chrome), but ```key(window)``` does work in Firefox

Answer (score 51):

If you want to exclude all the standard properties of the window object and view application-specific globals, this will print them to the Chrome console:

```js
{

    const standardGlobals = new Set(["window", "self", "document", "name", "location", "customElements", "history", "locationbar", "menubar", "personalbar", "scrollbars", "statusbar", "toolbar", "status", "closed", "frames", "length", "top", "opener", "parent", "frameElement", "navigator", "origin", "external", "screen", "innerWidth", "innerHeight", "scrollX", "pageXOffset", "scrollY", "pageYOffset", "visualViewport", "screenX", "screenY", "outerWidth", "outerHeight", "devicePixelRatio", "clientInformation", "screenLeft", "screenTop", "defaultStatus", "defaultstatus", "styleMedia", "onsearch", "isSecureContext", "performance", "onappinstalled", "onbeforeinstallprompt", "crypto", "indexedDB", "webkitStorageInfo", "sessionStorage", "localStorage", "onabort", "onblur", "oncancel", "oncanplay", "oncanplaythrough", "onchange", "onclick", "onclose", "oncontextmenu", "oncuechange", "ondblclick", "ondrag", "ondragend", "ondragenter", "ondragleave", "ondragover", "ondragstart", "ondrop", "ondurationchange", "onemptied", "onended", "onerror", "onfocus", "onformdata", "oninput", "oninvalid", "onkeydown", "onkeypress", "onkeyup", "onload", "onloadeddata", "onloadedmetadata", "onloadstart", "onmousedown", "onmouseenter", "onmouseleave", "onmousemove", "onmouseout", "onmouseover", "onmouseup", "onmousewheel", "onpause", "onplay", "onplaying", "onprogress", "onratechange", "onreset", "onresize", "onscroll", "onseeked", "onseeking", "onselect", "onstalled", "onsubmit", "onsuspend", "ontimeupdate", "ontoggle", "onvolumechange", "onwaiting", "onwebkitanimationend", "onwebkitanimationiteration", "onwebkitanimationstart", "onwebkittransitionend", "onwheel", "onauxclick", "ongotpointercapture", "onlostpointercapture", "onpointerdown", "onpointermove", "onpointerup", "onpointercancel", "onpointerover", "onpointerout", "onpointerenter", "onpointerleave", "onselectstart", "onselectionchange", "onanimationend", "onanimationiteration", "onanimationstart", "ontransitionrun", "ontransitionstart", "ontransitionend", "ontransitioncancel", "onafterprint", "onbeforeprint", "onbeforeunload", "onhashchange", "onlanguagechange", "onmessage", "onmessageerror", "onoffline", "ononline", "onpagehide", "onpageshow", "onpopstate", "onrejectionhandled", "onstorage", "onunhandledrejection", "onunload", "alert", "atob", "blur", "btoa", "cancelAnimationFrame", "cancelIdleCallback", "captureEvents", "clearInterval", "clearTimeout", "close", "confirm", "createImageBitmap", "fetch", "find", "focus", "getComputedStyle", "getSelection", "matchMedia", "moveBy", "moveTo", "open", "postMessage", "print", "prompt", "queueMicrotask", "releaseEvents", "requestAnimationFrame", "requestIdleCallback", "resizeBy", "resizeTo", "scroll", "scrollBy", "scrollTo", "setInterval", "setTimeout", "stop", "webkitCancelAnimationFrame", "webkitRequestAnimationFrame", "chrome", "caches", "ondevicemotion", "ondeviceorientation", "ondeviceorientationabsolute", "originAgentCluster", "cookieStore", "showDirectoryPicker", "showOpenFilePicker", "showSaveFilePicker", "speechSynthesis", "onpointerrawupdate", "trustedTypes", "crossOriginIsolated", "openDatabase", "webkitRequestFileSystem", "webkitResolveLocalFileSystemURL"]);

    for (const key of Object.keys(window)) {
        if (!standardGlobals.has(key)) {
            console.log(key)
        }
    }
}
```

The script works well as a bookmarklet. To use the script as a bookmarklet, create a new bookmark and replace the URL with the following:

```js
javascript:(() => {
    const standardGlobals = new Set(["window", "self", "document", "name", "location", "customElements", "history", "locationbar", "menubar", "personalbar", "scrollbars", "statusbar", "toolbar", "status", "closed", "frames", "length", "top", "opener", "parent", "frameElement", "navigator", "origin", "external", "screen", "innerWidth", "innerHeight", "scrollX", "pageXOffset", "scrollY", "pageYOffset", "visualViewport", "screenX", "screenY", "outerWidth", "outerHeight", "devicePixelRatio", "clientInformation", "screenLeft", "screenTop", "defaultStatus", "defaultstatus", "styleMedia", "onsearch", "isSecureContext", "performance", "onappinstalled", "onbeforeinstallprompt", "crypto", "indexedDB", "webkitStorageInfo", "sessionStorage", "localStorage", "onabort", "onblur", "oncancel", "oncanplay", "oncanplaythrough", "onchange", "onclick", "onclose", "oncontextmenu", "oncuechange", "ondblclick", "ondrag", "ondragend", "ondragenter", "ondragleave", "ondragover", "ondragstart", "ondrop", "ondurationchange", "onemptied", "onended", "onerror", "onfocus", "onformdata", "oninput", "oninvalid", "onkeydown", "onkeypress", "onkeyup", "onload", "onloadeddata", "onloadedmetadata", "onloadstart", "onmousedown", "onmouseenter", "onmouseleave", "onmousemove", "onmouseout", "onmouseover", "onmouseup", "onmousewheel", "onpause", "onplay", "onplaying", "onprogress", "onratechange", "onreset", "onresize", "onscroll", "onseeked", "onseeking", "onselect", "onstalled", "onsubmit", "onsuspend", "ontimeupdate", "ontoggle", "onvolumechange", "onwaiting", "onwebkitanimationend", "onwebkitanimationiteration", "onwebkitanimationstart", "onwebkittransitionend", "onwheel", "onauxclick", "ongotpointercapture", "onlostpointercapture", "onpointerdown", "onpointermove", "onpointerup", "onpointercancel", "onpointerover", "onpointerout", "onpointerenter", "onpointerleave", "onselectstart", "onselectionchange", "onanimationend", "onanimationiteration", "onanimationstart", "ontransitionrun", "ontransitionstart", "ontransitionend", "ontransitioncancel", "onafterprint", "onbeforeprint", "onbeforeunload", "onhashchange", "onlanguagechange", "onmessage", "onmessageerror", "onoffline", "ononline", "onpagehide", "onpageshow", "onpopstate", "onrejectionhandled", "onstorage", "onunhandledrejection", "onunload", "alert", "atob", "blur", "btoa", "cancelAnimationFrame", "cancelIdleCallback", "captureEvents", "clearInterval", "clearTimeout", "close", "confirm", "createImageBitmap", "fetch", "find", "focus", "getComputedStyle", "getSelection", "matchMedia", "moveBy", "moveTo", "open", "postMessage", "print", "prompt", "queueMicrotask", "releaseEvents", "requestAnimationFrame", "requestIdleCallback", "resizeBy", "resizeTo", "scroll", "scrollBy", "scrollTo", "setInterval", "setTimeout", "stop", "webkitCancelAnimationFrame", "webkitRequestAnimationFrame", "chrome", "caches", "ondevicemotion", "ondeviceorientation", "ondeviceorientationabsolute", "originAgentCluster", "cookieStore", "showDirectoryPicker", "showOpenFilePicker", "showSaveFilePicker", "speechSynthesis", "onpointerrawupdate", "trustedTypes", "crossOriginIsolated", "openDatabase", "webkitRequestFileSystem", "webkitResolveLocalFileSystemURL"]);
    for (const key of Object.keys(window)) {
        if (!standardGlobals.has(key)) {
            console.log(key)
        }
    }
})()
```

Comment: This is a list of current Chrome and Firefox default globals: http://pastebin.com/wNj3kfg0

Comment: Unfortunately an outdated list, but still very helpful! If I had more time I'd contribute a way to get the current standardGlobals in a blank window in an easy way (remind me in a few hours and I should have some time for that, in case anyone is interested and can't do it themselves).

Comment: Updated for 2021, but some of the other answers seem evergreen.

Answer (score 46):

The `window` object contains all the public variables, so you can type it in the console and then expand to view all variables/attributes/functions.

[image: chrome-show-all-variables-expand-window-object]

Comment: Nice! By far the easiest way since you can recursively expand variables.

Comment: This is a good method to see `document` as the browser does by elements and `document.` document(dot) for document properties.  And `window.document` clarifies a lot of confusion about [window vs document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript)

Answer (score 16):

Type the following statement in the javascript console:

```
debugger
```

Now you can inspect the global scope using the normal debug tools.

To be fair, you'll get *everything* in the `window` scope, including browser built-ins, so it might be sort of a needle-in-a-haystack experience. :/

Answer (score 10):

David Walsh has a nice solution for this. Here is my take on this, combining his solution with what has been discovered on this thread as well.

https://davidwalsh.name/global-variables-javascript

```
x = {};
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.onload = function() {
    var standardGlobals = Object.keys(iframe.contentWindow);
    for(var b in window) { 
      const prop = window[b];
      if(window.hasOwnProperty(b) && prop && !prop.toString().includes('native code') && !standardGlobals.includes(b)) {
        x[b] = prop;
      }
    }
    console.log(x)
};
iframe.src = 'about:blank';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

`x` now has only the globals.

Comment: `prop.toString` seems to not exist everywhere, so the condition could be more defensive `if(window.hasOwnProperty(b) && prop && (prop.toString && !prop.toString().includes('native code')) && !standardGlobals.includes(b))`

Answer (score 9):

To view any variable in chrome, go to "Sources", and then "Watch" and add it. If you add the "window" variable here then you can expand it and explore.

Answer (score 8):

I ended using this for debugging purposes:

```
for (aProperty in window) {
    try{
        console.log(aProperty +':'+JSON.stringify(window[aProperty]));
    }catch{}
}
```

`try` is used to avoid `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`
Then `Save as...` console output to a file and manipulate further.

Comment: chat gpt advies using `console.dir(window)` dunno if any better

Answer (score 7):

**List the variable and their values**

```
for(var b in window) { if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) console.log(b+" = "+window[b]); }
```

[image]

**Display the value of a particular variable object**

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(content_of_some_variable_object))
```

[image]

*Sources: comment from @northern-bradley and answer from @nick-craver*

Answer (score 6):

Updated method from same [article](https://davidwalsh.name/global-variables-javascript) Avindra mentioned — injects iframe and compare its `contentWindow` properties to global window properties.

```js
(function() {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.onload = function() {
    var iframeKeys = Object.keys(iframe.contentWindow);
    Object.keys(window).forEach(function(key) {
      if(!(iframeKeys.indexOf(key) > -1)) {
        console.log(key);
      }
    });
  };
  iframe.src = 'about:blank';
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
})();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.  No iframe is created - does it have to be manually triggered?

Answer (score 5):

Type: `this` in the console,

to get the `window object` I think(?), I think it's basically the same as typing `window` in the console.

It works at least in Firefox & chrome.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try this [Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/) extension for Chrome.

Comment: Though it does look nice, this solution sounds a bit of using a cannon to kill a mosquito to me.

Comment: Maybe. It's the only thing I found that shows objects/functions/etc. the way firebug in FF does (under the DOM-tab in the extension). It's a bit slow though.

Comment: As of May 17, your link is broken. Is this the same? http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/

Comment: @beanland 7: yep, fixed it in the answer, thnx for warning

Answer (score 1):

As all "public variables" are in fact properties of the window object (of the window/tab you are looking at), you can just inspect the "window" object instead. If you have multiple frames, you will have to select the correct window object (like in Firebug) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple command:

```
console.log(window)
```

Comment: It returns "undefined"

Answer (score -1):

[image]