# Show all object methods in a list in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome, v8

I really love the Chrome console because it autocompletes all the object methods for me.

But it only shows one at a time and I have to press TAB to step to the next one.

Is there a way to show a list of all the autocompletion object methods?

Comment: Related: [View list of all JavaScript variables in Google Chrome Console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2934787/258127)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
console.dir( someObject );
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The auto complete showed a method, which did not appear in console.dir. Another note: Putting the object into the watch, and expanding the watch, shows similar output to console.dir (again missing a method that auto complete shows)

Comment: @giwyni Could you share details? Which object and which method?

Answer (score 2):

You could loop though and print them.  Here's an example for `window`:

```
for(var i in window) if(window.hasOwnProperty(i)) console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in recent versions (10+) of Chrome, you can just type the object name and it will build you a tree of the object:

```
someObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use 
console.log(someObject);

Ben McCormack's way works as well, you just need to be Paused on breakpoint (in Chrome DevTools > Sources )

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.getPrototypeOf

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(objectHere)
// or
console.dir(Object.getPrototypeOf(objectHere))
```