# How to get a Greasemonkey script to run both at @run-at document-start AND at @run-at document-end?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, startup

For my Greasemonkey script, there is part of the code that should run before the page is loaded (`@run-at document-start`) and another part of the code that should run after the document is loaded (`@run-at document-end`).
Is this possible?

- 1st part of script run
- page is loaded, document is ready
- 2nd part of script run

I'd rather not use jQuery for this.

I tried the `onload` event but it didn't work. I think the event cannot be attached if the document is not there yet?

```
window.document.onload = function(e){ 
    alert("document.onload" ); 
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The event you want is `DOMContentLoaded`.  Also, that is not how to use the `load` event.

Here's a complete script that demonstrates the various firing times:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Show page start event timing
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==
console.log ("==> Script start.", new Date() );

// 1ST PART OF SCRIPT RUN GOES HERE.
console.log ("==> 1st part of script run.", new Date() );

document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", DOM_ContentReady);
window.addEventListener ("load", pageFullyLoaded);

function DOM_ContentReady () {
    // 2ND PART OF SCRIPT RUN GOES HERE.
    // This is the equivalent of @run-at document-end
    console.log ("==> 2nd part of script run.", new Date() );
}

function pageFullyLoaded () {
    console.log ("==> Page is fully loaded, including images.", new Date() );
}

console.log ("==> Script end.", new Date() );
```

---

Typical results:

```
"==> Script start."                           2014-10-09T01:53:49.323Z
"==> 1st part of script run."                 2014-10-09T01:53:49.323Z
"==> Script end."                             2014-10-09T01:53:49.323Z
"==> 2nd part of script run."                 2014-10-09T01:53:49.385Z
"==> Page is fully loaded, including images." 2014-10-09T01:53:49.487Z
```

Comment: Related: [Difference between document.addEventListener and window.addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12045440/3258851)