# What's the scope of HTML body?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, document-body

I'm learning Javascript.

```
<input type="button" onclick="addP();">
```

This line works fine.Can I add click event to the body like this?

```
<body onclick="addP();">
```

When I click ,I got nothing shows up.But if I add width and height to body, it worked! But just in the limited scope.
If you add a background color,it will cover all of the window. The color indicate the window's scope, but not clickable(I don't know if this 'clickable' word exists , hope you understand).
I can't vote up because my reputation isn't enough.I will do it later…

Comment: Can you provide us with the code for the body? No point in posting the code that works fine

Comment: @Luke <body onclick='addP();'></body>

Comment: if your html is well formed, adding a click event to `body` will trigger anywhere you click on the page - assuming you don't have a more direct element you are clicking on that is preventing the event from bubbling up

Comment: What is the code for the function addP()?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m3ssssvp/1/

Comment: @CrayonViolent - If the `body` tag isn't taking the full width/height of the window and there's no other elements in `body` that expand that, it will look as if it isn't working.

Comment: If the body doesn't have any content then the height/width will be 0%. The body expands to the height/width of the content (Like a wrap) If you place <p>test</p> and click on the word test your function should trigger.

Comment: The click event will only fire for a click in/on the `<body>`. If the `<body>` has no content, then it's _0 px by 0 px_ and you can't possibly click on it to fire the event. The element surrounding the `<body>` element is the `<html>` element, if you're wondering what you are clicking on instead (but I wouldn't usually advise putting event listeners on a `<html>` over the `<body>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there isn't a fully-working example, here is one where I've set the `html` and `body` tags to be `100%` width and height, which make it clickable anywhere on the screen.

Then, I use [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event handlers (e.g., `onclick=''`), which are better to use in most cases.

And last, I create the `p` element (which I assume your `addP()` function is doing) using the [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) DOM method, add text to it, then append it to the `document.body` element with [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Keep in mind that, in practice, you generally do not ever want to add things like click handlers or mouse event handlers to the `body` element, since it will trigger on any of those events on the page. Instead, use an element that's a parent of the element, or [`document.addEventListener()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12045503/451969).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function ol(){
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function cl(){
        var p = document.createElement('p');

        p.textContent = 'Hello World!';

        document.body.appendChild(p);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m3ssssvp/2/

Comment: Becareful of the addEventListener incompatability with IE 8 and earlier. The mozilla dev site give details and polyfills https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @jeff - For the record, [neither is `Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Answer (score -3):

try expanding the body fully

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.height = '100%';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.width = '100%';
```

trigger this right when the document loads, or if you know CSS, use that equivalent.

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged in this question and if you plan to give a jQuery solution, I would recommend clearly pointing out this is jQuery since it isn't tagged.

Comment: he's using a function, so he knows javascript. this should be fine now.