# window.document.addEventListener vs window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom

`window.document.addEventListener = function(event) {...}`

`window.addEventListener = function(event) {...}`

What is the difference between these two lines of code? I get that window and document object are two different objects with different properties and [this site](http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/) provides a good visual guide to the difference. Still I don't see the difference between what these two lines of code are doing.

To further clarify: what is the difference in doing something like this:
`window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {...});`
and doing something like this `window.document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {...});`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between document.addEventListener and window.addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045440/difference-between-document-addeventlistener-and-window-addeventlistener)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `addEventListener` methods on most DOM objects, as well as on the `window` itself. Events bubble and trigger event listeners on the element on which the event starts and its ancestors.

The two pieces of code there *overwrite* the `addEventListener` on different levels.

If you were to call the *original* method, it would rarely (if ever) make any difference which of those objects you called it on. It would make a difference if you were to compare, for example:

```
window.addEventListener('click', handler);
document.querySelector('button', handler);
```

Since one would capture all the clicks in the document and the other would only capture those on the first button element.

Comment: what about `window.document.addEventListener('click', handler);`?

Comment: "If you were to call the original method, it would rarely (if ever) make any difference which of those objects you called it on."

Comment: `window.document` and `document`, there is no difference between them.