# Keydown not working for my eventlistener

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am confused as to why when I press a key, my function is not logging the keydown event?

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<h1> Start typing </h1>
```

Comment: It is working fine. Please check again. Also check for any errors in console.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the right approach has to be use the document object and not the window object.

A code like the following should work:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log("event", e);
});
```

Comment: @JDB I was just looking for a link to explain why to use document instead of window.

Comment: This might be useful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110338/window-document-addeventlistener-vs-window-addeventlistener/33110391#33110391

Comment: @Rajesh Correction: "code is working fine" _on your machine_. This answer may very well be a solution so long as 1) it works on the OP's browser and 2) it doesn't break other browsers. It is not at all irrelevant.

Comment: using document.addEventListener instead of window is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet seems to be okay. So it might have to do with the surrounding environment, where you run it.

(That is, if the other answers using `document` did not already help you.)

Please investigate the situation where it fails. A possible reason could be that the `keyEvent` is cancelled by any EventListener along the bubble way.

You are fetching the `keydown` at the top-most level, the window level (even higher than the document level).

If the bubbling is stopped along the event way, you won't see it.

Try for example

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will also prevent you from seeing the keydown in your orignal event listener.