# Vue JS - How to get window size whenever it changes

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm new to vuejs but I was trying to get the window size whenever I 
   resize it so that i can compare it to some value for a function that I 
   need to apply depending on the screen size. I also tried using the 
   watch property but not sure how to handle it so that's probably why it didn't work

```
  methods: {

    elem() {
     this.size = window.innerWidth;
     return this.size;
   },
  mounted() {
    if (this.elem < 767){ //some code }
   }
```

Comment: `document.addEventListener('resize', <yourfunction>);` ? I have no clue of `vue`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49381187/906113

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Put this code inside your Vue component:

```
created() {
  window.addEventListener("resize", this.myEventHandler);
},
destroyed() {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", this.myEventHandler);
},
methods: {
  myEventHandler(e) {
    // your code for handling resize...
  }
}
```

This will register your Vue method on component creation, trigger myEventHandler when the browser window is resized, and free up memory once your component is destroyed.

Comment: Works, but I really recommend debouncing this kind of events.

Comment: You can easily apply debounce to any vue method.

Comment: I know, just making a note for the OP

Comment: This answer says document should be preferred over window https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045440/difference-between-document-addeventlistener-and-window-addeventlistener

Comment: And the same answer also says that 'resize' is defined for window, but not for document

Comment: Fair enough, I will change to window

Comment: This code is only valid for singleton components, because it will share handlers across components. If you have multiple components they will stop working as soon as the first one is destroyed. The correct way is creating a binded function inside the view model (data).

Comment: The events gets fired for me only if the size of the browser is increased. When the size is reduced the event does not get fired. Has anybody similar issues?

Answer (score 18):

For Vue3, you may use the code below:

```
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener("resize", this.myEventHandler);
},
unmounted() {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", this.myEventHandler);
},
methods: {
  myEventHandler(e) {
    // your code for handling resize...
  }
}
```

destroyed and beforeDestroyed is deprecated in Vue3, hence you might want to use the beforeUnmount and unmounted

Answer (score 9):

## Simplest approach

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-window-size

### Preview

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueWindowSize from 'vue-window-size';

Vue.use(VueWindowSize);
```

You would then access it normally from your components like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>window width: {{ windowWidth }}</p>
    <p>window height: {{ windowHeight }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I wouldn't call installing a new library via NPM the "simplest" approach :). Especially since it wouldn't work if you're [using plain Vue from a CDN without build tools](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#without-build-tools).

Comment: I was NOT able to install `vue-window-size/option-api`

Answer (score 7):

I looked at the code of that library `vue-window-size`, and besides the additional logic, it's just adding an event listener on window resize, and it looks like it can be instructed to debounce. [Source](https://github.com/mya-ake/vue-window-size/blob/master/src/window-size.js)

The critical problem for me is that my Vue SPA app does not emit a window resize event when a vue-router route changes that makes the `<html>` element go from 1000px to 4000px, so it's causing me all kinds of problems watching a canvas element controlled by p5.js to redraw a wallpaper using `p5.resizeCanvas()`.

I have a different solution now that involves actively polling the page's offset height.

The first thing to be aware of is JavaScript memory management, so to avoid memory leaks, I put setInterval in the `created` lifecycle method and clearInterval in the `beforeDestroy` lifecycle method:

```
created() {
    this.refreshScrollableArea = setInterval(() => {
        const { offsetWidth, offsetHeight } = document.getElementById('app');
        this.offsetWidth = offsetWidth;
        this.offsetHeight = offsetHeight;
    }, 100);
},

beforeDestroy() {
    return clearInterval(this.refreshScrollableArea);
},
```

As hinted in the above code, I also placed some initial state:

```
data() {
    const { offsetWidth, offsetHeight } = document.querySelector('#app');

    return {
        offsetWidth,
        offsetHeight,
        refreshScrollableArea: undefined,
    };
},
```

> **Note:** if you are using `getElementById` with something like `this.id` (ie: an element that is a child in this component), `document.getElementById(this.id)` will be undefined because DOM elements load outer-to-inner, so if you see an error stemming from the `data` instantiation, set the width/height to `0` initially.

Then, I put a watcher on `offsetHeight` to listen for height changes and perform business logic:

```
    watch: {
        offsetHeight() {
            console.log('offsetHeight changed', this.offsetHeight);

            this.state = IS_RESET;
            this.setState(this.sketch);
            return this.draw(this.sketch);
        },
    },
```

**Conclusion:** I tested with `performance.now()` and:

```
document.querySelector('#app').offsetHeight 
document.getElementById('app').offsetHeight
document.querySelector('#app').getClientBoundingRect().height
```

all execute in about the exact same amount of time: `0.2ms`, so the above code is costing about 0.2ms every 100ms. I currently find that reasonable in my app including after I adjust for slow clients that operate an order of magnitude slower than my localmachine.

Here is the test logic for your own R&D:

```
const t0 = performance.now();
const { offsetWidth, offsetHeight } = document.getElementById('app');
const t1 = performance.now();

console.log('execution time:', (t1 - t0), 'ms');
```

**Bonus:** if you get any performance issue due to long-running execution time on your `setInterval` function, try wrapping it in a double-requestAnimationFrame:

```
created() {
    this.refreshScrollableArea = setInterval(() => {
        return requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            const { offsetWidth, offsetHeight } = document.getElementById(this.id);
            this.offsetWidth = offsetWidth;
            this.offsetHeight = offsetHeight;
        }));
    }, 100);
},
```

`requestAnimationFrame` itself a person should research. I will leave it out of the scope of this answer.

In closing, another idea I researched later, but am not using is to use a recursive `setTimeout` function with a dynamic timeout on it (ie: a timeout that decays after the page loads); however, if you consider the recursive setTimeout technique, be conscious of callstack/function-queue length and tail call optimization. Stack size could run away on you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using composition api in vue 3, you may use following code

```
onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
  handleWindowSizeChange();
});
onUnmounted(() => {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowSizeChange);
});
const handleWindowSizeChange = () => {
// your code
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked from me was Vuetify (and yes, I've tried most solutions that were suggested on this page).  For some reason, adding an event listener (which seems to have the most up-votes on this thread) didn't work for my project.  I'm not 100% sure why, but some comments seem to suggest that it's a problem with non-singleton component apps (whatever that means)?

I also found a few extensions that are out there in the ecosystem (including something called [vue-resize-directive >>](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.resize), but they only seem compatible with Vue 2!! :-(

Anyway, the solution that did work was this:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-resize-directive/

It's a bit of a faff to [install Vuetify in an existing project >>](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#existing-projects), but once installed its use as a directive means that it adds minimal code in your component.

```html
    <div v-resize="myResizeFunction">
        <!-- blah -->
    </div>
```

Where `myResizeFunction()` is the event-handler callback function in your JavaScript.

Unfortunately, unlike the afore-mentioned vue-resize-directive, the Vuetify version of the directive doesn't seem to have any modifiers (such as the ability to define a debounce delay, for example).  But it works well enough for my needs.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this anywhere anytime

```
methods: {
    //define below method first.
    winWidth: function () {
        setInterval(() => {
            var w = window.innerWidth;
            if (w < 768) {
                this.clientsTestimonialsPages = 1
            } else if (w < 960) {
                this.clientsTestimonialsPages = 2
            } else if (w < 1200) {
                this.clientsTestimonialsPages = 3
            } else {
                this.clientsTestimonialsPages = 4
            }
        }, 100);
    }
},
mounted() {
    //callback once mounted
    this.winWidth()
}
```

Comment: It does work, but there's really no need to run that function 10x per second, when an event listener will fire only as often as needed, as in the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes @hanenbro I published this long time ago and now I realized this can run without setInterval and just callback my method as Goran's answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49381030/5748470)