# v-if - condition based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

im trying to use v-if to render 2 buttons in different containers on page, depending on screen size
is there way how to change parent of items in @media or way how to use screen size in v-if condition?

i tried

```
<div v-if="window.innerWidth < 860">
<!-- Some code -->
</div>
```

but it throws me "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerWidth')"

(when i use just media query, there appears bug with radio btns, when they needs 2 clicks to get :checked styles)
when i tried @media, in fact there was 4 buttons, that binded to 2 variables

```
<!-- button code -->
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="month-season" id="month" value="month" v-model="monthSeason">
  <null-button>
     <img src="../assets/green-smile.png" alt="#" id="month-icon">
     text
  </null-button>
</label>


<!-- null-button -->
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
<div>

<!-- styles for button -->
<style>
    .month-season {
        text-align: right;

        label {
            .container {
                color: rgba(45, 206, 137, 1);
                background: white;
                img {
                    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
                }
            }
            input:checked + .parent .container {
                background: rgba(45, 206, 137, 1);
                color: white;
                img {
                    filter: brightness(1000%);
                }
            }
            input {
                appearance: none;
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

Error message when I use `window.innerWidth`
[image: when using window.innerWidth]

Comment: A site note: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue JS - How to get window size whenever it changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380830/vue-js-how-to-get-window-size-whenever-it-changes)

Comment: @MoritzRingler for vue3 i suggested a more modern approach. so it's not a duplicate. the issue you pointed is outdated

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev You are using the exact same method though, you are just using a different approach to check the width - which is not related to Vue or this question, right?

Comment: @MoritzRingler the OP tagged vuejs3 and my answer is strongly Vue3 focused and made for Vue3 only, it's not generic

Answer (score 0):

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

All JS expression that you use in a template are executed in a so called template context. It contains all stuff declared in a component and does NOT contains JS globals like `window` and its props like `alert`. So you should use `window` outside a template or to add to `app.config.globalProperties`.

But adding `window` to the context doesn't solve you problem because JS expressions using it aren't reactive and your code would work only on initial component rendering.

So you should go reactive here. A common Vue3 approach would be using composables here.

We could use 2 different approaches here. Either using [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) or `window.innerWidth` as you tried.

With `matchMedia` you can go with any CSS media query you like.

So in the both cases you listen for appropriate events and update `ref` that is used further in a template.

If you listen on `window` don't forget to remove the listener when the component is unmounted otherwise you will have problems of ghost event handlers.

So your `matchMedia` composable:

```
import {ref} from 'vue';

export function useMatchMedia(query){

    const match = window.matchMedia(query);

    const isMatching = ref(match.matches);

    match.addEventListener('change', e => isMatching.value = e.matches);

    return isMatching;
}
```

Your `window.innerWidth` composable:

```
import {ref, onUnmounted} from 'vue';

export function useInnerWidth(query){

    const match = window.matchMedia(query);

    const width = ref(window.innerWidth);

    const syncWidth = () => width.value = window.innerWidth;

    window.addEventListener('resize', syncWidth);

    onUnmounted(() => window.removeEventListener('resize', syncWidth));

    return width;
}
```

And the usage:

```
<script setup>

import { useMatchMedia } from './useMatchMedia';
const smallScreen = useMatchMedia('(max-width: 859px)');

import { useInnerWidth } from './useInnerWidth';
const innerWidth = useInnerWidth();

</script>

<template>
  <h1 v-if="smallScreen">I'm a smaller screen</h1>
  <h1 v-else>I'm a bigger screen</h1>
  <p v-if="innerWidth < 860">Smaller screen width: {{innerWidth}}</p>
  <p v-else>Bigger screen width: {{innerWidth}}</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using [useWindowSize](https://vueuse.org/core/useWindowSize/) or [useElementSize](https://vueuse.org/core/useElementSize/).