# .on[event name] vs addEventListener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener

I tried to create copy handler but I couldn't.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <span class = "test"></span>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
function handleCopy() {
    document.querySelector("span.test").innerText = "Copied";
}
window.oncopy = handleCopy;
```

and I copy from index.html, but js doesn't change span. but changing the js code to like this, The span is change.

```js
function handleCopy() {
    document.querySelector("span.test").innerText = "Copied";
}
window.addEventListener("copy", handleCopy);
```

Why did that happen?
Sorry my terrible English :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between document.addEventListener and window.addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045440/difference-between-document-addeventlistener-and-window-addeventlistener)

Comment: It's true i din't see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/copy_event), However [oncopy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/oncopy) is experimental I still recommend addEventListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because there's no `oncopy` property in `window` object. If you'd open the console, and wrote "window.onco", there's no `oncopy` in the suggestions. In the documentation this is not very clear, but when taking a look at [Event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#event_handlers), `oncopy` event is not listed, nor it can't be found on the following [Event handlers implemented from elsewhere](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#event_handlers_implemented_from_elsewhere) list. Instead, you can find it from [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#events) list, which of prologue says: "*Listen to these events using addEventListener()*". It looks like the article needs a small fix, as the prologue says also that these events can be attached with `oneventname` property, obviously that's not true in all cases.

Comment: No the docs are correct, "the instance" they talk about is just not an instance of `Window`.

Comment: @Kaiido "_the oneventname property of this interface_" I'd assume "_this_" here refers to `Window` ..? Maybe the docs was changed recently, now it talks about interface.

Comment: Ok I'll admit this is unclear, and anyway, DOMContentLoaded is in this list and it doesn't have an IDL handler.

Answer (score 0):

The `copy` event is not a [GlobalEventHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/) and thus doesn't have its own IDL handler available on `window`.
This event is defined to fire on an HTMLElement and that's where the [`oncopy` IDL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/oncopy) is accessible:

```js
console.log("oncopy" in HTMLElement.prototype);
```

And because it's a [DocumentAndElementEventHandler](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#documentandelementeventhandlers), you will also find it on `document`.

So if you want to catch the event on the `window`, that will be through bubbling and thanks to the `addEventListener()` method.

```js
addEventListener("copy", (evt) => {
  console.log("copied");
});
```

```html
<input value="copy me">
```

Otherwise, you can use `document`'s or any parent HTMLElement's event handler (e.g `document.body`):

```js
document.oncopy = (evt) => {
  console.log("copied");
}
```

```html
<input value="copy me">
```