# Difference between screen and window property?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications

In my Web application , am in need to use the browser window's Height & Width. So I used **Screen.Width , Screen.Height** properties in JavaScript to get the Width & Height. While am surfing I got another property as **Window.Width , Window.Height**. Can anyone tell me , which property gives me the Size of Browser window.....***Screen (or) Window ?***

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Issa Qandil- Thank's for the Link. But my question is What does WINDOW  refers to ? What does Screen refers to ? either my Monitor size (or) Browser window size ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`screen` is actually `window.screen` since `window` is the context for globals.

A `window` object (obtained through `document.defaultView`) returns information about both the window and the viewport. To get the application window size use `window.outerHeight`, to get viewport size use `window.innerHeight`.

The `screen` object refers to the actual monitor window or desktop size. Note that if you have a multi-mon setup then you will have multiple `screen` objects. A `window` object belongs to a single `screen`, though not very `window` belongs to the same `screen`. I do not know what happens when a browser window spans multiple `screen`s.

From all this, you can determine that if you are running a full-screen browser then `window.outerHeight == window.innerHeight == screen.height`.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screen and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window

Comment: When a browser window spans multiple screens the window.screen object depends on where the most of is placed. For example if you have more than half of your browser on Monitor A and the rest on Monitor B then window.screen will be of Monitor A.

Answer (score 13):

window.screen.height

window.screen.width

height/width of the screen or monitor in pixels

window.screen.availHeight

window.screen.availWidth

height/width of the screen or monitor, in pixels, *minus* permanent or semi-permanent user interface features displayed by the operating system, such as the Taskbar on Windows or device status bar on smart phones

window.innerHeight

window.innerWidth

height/width of the content area of the browser window including, if rendered, the horizontal/vertical scrollbar

window.outerHeight

window.outerWidth

height/width of the outside of the browser window

Answer (score 1):

[What is the difference between window, screen, and document in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript?rq=1) is pretty much this same question. To paraphrase the accepted answer and add some info that I feel it could use:

`window` in the root object. Any variables or functions you define are in some way children of the `window` object. So if you do `var something="blah"` in a script tag, you can later access that variable in 3 ways - `something`, `window.something` or `window["something"]`.

`screen` is one of the children of window that is created by the browser. however, for the same reason that you can access `window.something` as `something`, you can access it either as `window.screen` or `screen`. This contains the properties of the actual screen, and it is where I would go to get the details you want (unless you have access to a framework like jQuery or Prototype, in which case they can probably give you this information without worries about browser compatibility).