# what are the differences between $document and $window?

Tags: angularjs

That is my question, I am working with AngularJS and I need to know what are the differences between `$document` and `$window` because I am doing some directives that I need to work depending on screen resolution, so I need to aim to some different points before I start defining where that directives must to called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be same as the difference between `window` and `document` objects in JavaScript. `window` is the visible part so you should probably work with that.

[What is the difference between window, screen, and document in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript)