# How to import jquery using ES6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, browserify, semantic-ui

I'm writing a new app using (JavaScript) `ES6` syntax through `babel` transpiler and the `preset-es2015` plugins, as well as `semantic-ui` for the style.

#### index.js

```
import * as stylesheet from '../assets/styles/app.scss';
import * as jquery2 from '../dist/scripts/jquery.min';
import * as jquery3 from '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min';

console.log($('my-app'));
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<body>
<script src="dist/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Project structure

```
.
├── app/
│   ├── index.js
├── assets/
├── dist/
│   ├── scripts/
│   │   ├── jquery.min.js
├── index.html
├── node_modules/
│   ├── jquery/
│   │   ├── dist/
│   │   │   ├── jquery.min.js
├── package.json
└── tests/
```

#### package.json

```
  …
  "scripts": {
    "build:app": "browserify -e ./app/index.js -o ./dist/app.js",
    "copy:jquery": "cpy 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' ./dist/scripts/",
    …
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.3.x",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.3.x",
    "babelify": "7.2.x",
    "cpy": "3.4.x",
    "npm-run-all": "1.4.x",
    "sassify": "0.9.x",
    "semantic-ui": "2.1.x",
    …
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [ "babelify", { "presets": [ "es2015"]}],
      [ "sassify", { "auto-inject": true}]
    ]
  }
```

#### Question

Using classic `<script>` tag to import `jquery` works fine, but I'm trying to use the ES6 syntax.

- How do I import `jquery` to satisfy `semantic-ui` using ES6 import syntax?
- Should I import from the `node_modules/` directory or my `dist/` (where I copy everything)?

Comment: Well, importing from `dist` doesn't make sense since that is your distribution folder with production ready app. Building your app should take what's inside node modules and add it to the dist folder, jQuery included.

Comment: Nor does importing from an *scss* file. Unless there's some awesome plugin I'm missing out on!

Comment: @RGraham it's called [sassify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sassify), a browserify plugin. I'm inspiring myself from [oncletom gist](https://gist.github.com/oncletom/1e233f2100c4e0877922)

Comment: I will check that out, thanks!

Comment: @RGraham - the syntax looks odd, but using "require" for css / sass files is encouraged with build tools like webpack + babel. eg. require("../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");

Comment: @arcseldon Agreed, that's an interesting approach to modularisation - glad I asked!

Comment: no worries, appreciate here we are discussing ES6 syntax for module import and not commonjs but ultimately same concepts at play.

Comment: Why not use it globally. What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

#### index.js

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
// export for others scripts to use
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

First, as **@nem** suggested in comment, the import should be done from `node_modules/`:

> Well, importing from `dist/` doesn't make sense since that is your distribution folder with production ready app. Building your app should take what's inside `node_modules/` and add it to the `dist/` folder, jQuery included.

Next, the glob –`* as`– is wrong as I know what object I'm importing (*e.g.* `jQuery` and `$`), so a straigforward [import statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Syntax) will work.

Last you need to expose it to other scripts using the `window.$ = $`.

Then, I import as both `$` and `jQuery` to cover all usages, `browserify` remove import duplication, so no overhead here! ^o^y

Comment: Not sure if any y'all still around but could you explain the need for `window.$ = $`. I don't understand why that's needed. Won't other scripts be automatically bundled into a single `js` script when browserify does it's magic?

Comment: May be for development purpose?

Comment: @qarthandso `window` is a global object so attaching `jquery` or `$` to it make it available to everywhere (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9895261/802365)

Comment: Why not just have `import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';`? Why so many imports?

Comment: How you find the name exact class name , ie `jQuery` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj it's in the [source of jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/52e24471c89b80e6208b4987bb76994e64c1e489/src/exports/global.js#L31)

Comment: I either get ```Module '"jquery"' has no exported member 'jQuery'``` or ```Module '"jquery"' has no default export``` what am I missing please?

Comment: Older versions of jQuery don't use named exports.  Newer versions do.  The method of import depends on which version of jQuery you're using.

Comment: How do we achieve this with jQuery 2.x then?

Comment: @IronSean I would say import {jQuery} from 'jquery'; window.$ = jQuery; window.jQuery = jQuery;

Comment: ```import "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js";

const element = $("#abc");```

Comment: I get the same error as daslicht even though I'm using the most recent version (3.5.1).

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez and if I don't want make it available to everywhere I can not assign it to window? I created [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63247885/why-import-as-from-jquery-doesnt-work) but it was closed. I don't understand why lodash working and jquery not.

Answer (score 78):

Based on the solution of Édouard Lopez, but in two lines:

```
import jQuery from "jquery";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

Comment: This worked for me, whereas the accepted answer approach didn't... I used much the same:  import $ from 'jquery'; window.jQuery = $;window.$ = $;

Comment: one line : `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

Comment: @NabilBaadillah `require` (CommonJS) is not `import` (ES module) and the one-liner doesn't seem possible with `import`. (Someone cares?)

Comment: One-liner is definitely possible: `import jQuery from "jquery"; window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;`

Comment: It works until I refresh a page! bellow error occur: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Answer (score 45):

You can create a module converter like below:

```js
// jquery.module.js
import 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'
export default window.jQuery.noConflict(true)
```

This will remove global variables introduced by jQuery (`jQuery` & `$`) and export jQuery object as default.

Then use it in your script:

```js
// script.js
import $ from "./jquery.module.js";
    
$(function(){
  $('body').text('youpi!');
});
```

Do not forget to load it as a module in your document:

```html
<script type='module' src='./script.js'></script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/a59ETj3Yo2PJ0Aqkxbeu?p=preview

Comment: This one helped! I generally like to try out basics before using any IDE/DevEnv. Without using Node/NPM/Babble I wanted to understand ES6 import and export. I had managed to get basic import and export working but was struggling with jquery inclusion. I had my custom code written as module but kept referencing jquery in its traditional way using the script tag in html. So I ended up having 2 script tags one to include jquery and other to include app.js. With your answer, I could get rid of my first jquery script tag and used the intermediate jquery.module.js as you suggested.

Comment: This solution also allows to extend jquery with libraries that build on top of it. `import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js";
import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js";
import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/notify/0.4.2/notify.js";

// export jquery with cookies and notify
export default window.jQuery.noConflict(true);`

Comment: This one works in TypeScript.

Comment: This allowed me to get type checking within nvim in pure JS! I used `import $ from "jquery"` for type checking (I guess the lsp looks at the jquery.js I have sitting next to main.js?) and an import map to point `"jquery"` to `jquery.module.js`. Many thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Import the entire JQuery's contents in the Global scope. This inserts $ into the current scope, containing all the exported bindings from the JQuery.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Now the $ belongs to the window object.

Comment: this worked for me. The top "import {jQuery as $} from 'jquery';" gives an error saying "jQuery" not found.

Comment: I tested all the above codes and just this worked for me.
also, I added `window.$ = window.jQuery = $;` for those codes that are before load event

Comment: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ! Why?

Answer (score 13):

If it helps anyone, javascript import statements are hoisted. Thus, if a library has a dependency (eg bootstrap) on jquery in the global namespace (window), this will NOT work:

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min';
```

This is because the import of bootstrap is hoisted and evaluated before jQuery is attached to window.

One way to get around this is to not import jQuery directly, but instead import a module which itself imports jQuery AND attaches it to the window.

```
import jQuery from './util/leaked-jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min';
```

where `leaked-jquery` looks like

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
export default $;
export { jQuery };
```

EG, https://github.com/craigmichaelmartin/weather-app--birch/blob/4d9f3b03719e0a2ea3fb5ddbbfc453a10e9843c6/javascript/util/leak_jquery.js

Comment: Why there is `import jQuery from './util/leaked-jquery';` and not `import $ from './util/leaked-jquery';`

Comment: If I call `log( window.$ )` inside the leaked-jquery file it is undefined. Why?

Answer (score 10):

webpack users, add the below to your `plugins` array.

```
let plugins = [
  // expose $ and jQuery to global scope.
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
];
```

Comment: What's the pro of this approach ? Cause you're binding yourself to your building tool here.

Comment: this is the only way I got it working. I tried `import {$, jQuery} from 'jquery';` but id didn't work, I believe because it's not defined (imported) in other modules.

Comment: This is the best solution for webpack users because jQuery should available globally in all files, without the redundant import statements.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer did not work for me 
**note : using rollup js** dont know if this answer belongs here 
after
npm i --save jquery
in custom.js

```
import {$, jQuery} from 'jquery';
```

or

```
import {jQuery as $} from 'jquery';
```

i was getting **error** :
Module ...node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js does not export **jQuery**
or
Module ...node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js does not export **$**
**rollup.config.js**

```
export default {
    entry: 'source/custom',
    dest: 'dist/custom.min.js',
    plugins: [
        inject({
            include: '**/*.js',
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            // $: 'jquery'
        }),
        nodeResolve({
            jsnext: true,
        }),
        babel(),
        // uglify({}, minify),
    ],
    external: [],
    format: 'iife', //'cjs'
    moduleName: 'mycustom',
};
```

instead of rollup inject, tried

```
commonjs({
   namedExports: {
     // left-hand side can be an absolute path, a path
     // relative to the current directory, or the name
     // of a module in node_modules
     // 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js': [ '$' ]
     // 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js': [ 'jQuery' ]
        'jQuery': [ '$' ]
},
format: 'cjs' //'iife'
};
```

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-eslint": "6.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-register": "6.9.0",
    "eslint": "2.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "1.8.1",
    "rollup": "0.33.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "2.6.1",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-inject": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "uglify-js": "2.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
  },
```

**This worked :**
removed the rollup inject and commonjs plugins

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
```

then in custom.js

```
$(function () {
        console.log('Hello jQuery');
});
```

Comment: It looks like `namedExports` doesn't exist anymore in the commonjs plugin

Answer (score 8):

I did not see this exact syntax posted yet, and it worked for me in an ES6/Webpack environment:

```js
import $ from "jquery";
```

Taken directly from [jQuery's NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery). Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

Pika is a CDN that takes care of providing module versions of popular packages

```
<script type='module'>
    import * as $ from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/jquery';

    // use it!
    $('#myDev').on('click', alert);
</script>
```

Skypack is Pika, so you could also use: `import * as $ from 'https://cdn.pika.dev/jquery@^3.5.1';`

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using any JS build tools/NPM, then you can directly include Jquery as:

```
import  'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js';
const $ = window.$;
```

You may skip import(Line 1) if you already included jquery using script tag under head.

Comment: I don't know why, but this one worked for me when no others did. Any import statement other than the bare `import 'filepath/jquery.js'` threw some error about the module not exporting the function I wanted or $ not being a function or just a SyntaxError at the sight of the word `from`.

Comment: @GalacticKetchup I also agree, mine worked too while the rest didnt. @VNN456 kindly explain why use `const $ = window.$` because in my code it doesnt affect the functionality whether I include that const or not. so probably there is something I'm missing out unknowingly by not reassigning the window object.

Answer (score 1):

```
import {jQuery as $} from 'jquery';
```

Comment: it says jQuery not found. The other answer worked "import * as $ from 'jquery';". Do you know why that happens? My JS file where I'm importing jquery is part of an Angular/Typescript file

Answer (score 1):

My project stack is: **ParcelJS + WordPress**

WordPress got ***jQuery v1.12.4*** itself and I have also import ***jQuery v3^*** as module for other depending modules as well as `bootstrap/js/dist/collapse`, for example... Unfortunately, I can’t leave only one jQuery version due to other WordPress modular dependencies.
And ofcourse there is conflict arises between two jquery version. Also keep in mind we got two modes for this project running Wordpress(Apache) / ParcelJS (NodeJS), witch make everything little bit difficulty. So at solution for this conflict was searching, sometimes the project broke on the left, sometimes on the right side.
SO... My finall solution (I hope it so...) is:

```js
    import $ from 'jquery'
    import 'popper.js'
    import 'bootstrap/js/dist/collapse'
    import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown'
    import 'signalr'

    if (typeof window.$ === 'undefined') {
        window.$ = window.jQ = $.noConflict(true);
    }

    if (process) {
        if (typeof window.jQuery === 'undefined') {
            window.$ = window.jQuery = $.noConflict(true);
        }
    }

    jQ('#some-id').do('something...')    

    /* Other app code continuous below.......... */
```

I still didn’t understand how myself, but this method works. Errors and conflicts of two jQuery version no longer arise

Answer (score 1):

```
import $ from 'jquery'

// export for others scripts to use
window.$ = window.jQuery = $
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer shows how to import jQuery statically.

However, jQuery is a big package and we often want to load only if or when it's needed. So, for completeness, here's how to load jQuery dynamically e.g. within a function:

```
async function showStatus(statusMessage) {
    if (typeof window.jQuery === 'undefined') {
        window.jQuery = await import('jquery').default;
        window.$ = window.jQuery;
    } 

    jQuery('#status').html(statusMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, install and save them in package.json:

```
npm i --save jquery
npm i --save jquery-ui-dist
```

Secondly, add a alias in webpack configuration:

```
resolve: {
  root: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
  ],
  alias: {
    'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
  },
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.json'],
}
```

It work for me with the last jquery(3.2.1) and jquery-ui(1.12.1).

See my blog for detail: http://code.tonytuan.org/2017/03/webpack-import-jquery-ui-in-es6-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Import jquery (I installed with 'npm install jquery@1.9.1')

```
import 'jquery/jquery.js';
```

Put all your code that depends on jquery inside this method

```
+function ($) { 
    // your code
}(window.jQuery);
```

or declare variable $ after import

```
var $ = window.$
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the alread-buildy jQuery (from jquery.org) and all the solutions mentioned here didn't work, how I fixed this issue was adding the following lines which should make it work on nearly every environment:

```
 export default  ( typeof module === 'object' && module.exports && typeof module.exports.noConflict === 'function' )
    ? module.exports.noConflict(true)
    : ( typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this ).jQuery.noConflict(true)
```

Comment: Ivan Castellanos you should expand your example to better understand how to apply it

Answer (score 0):

You can import like this

```
import("jquery").then((jQuery) => {
  window.$ = jQuery;
  window.jQuery = jQuery;
  import("bootstrap").then((_bs)=>{
    $(function() {});
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Webpack 4, the answer is to use the `ProvidePlugin`. Their [documentation specifically covers angular.js with jquery](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery-with-angular-1) use case:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
});
```

The issue is that when using `import` syntax angular.js and jquery will always be imported before you have a chance to assign jquery to window.jQuery (`import` statements will always run first no matter where they are in the code!). This means that angular will always see window.jQuery as undefined until you use `ProvidePlugin`.