# How to import jQuery UI using ES6/ES7 syntax?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, reactjs, npm, redux

I am trying to use some jQuery UI functionality in my reactJS/Redux application. I've imported both jQuery and jQuery UI using:

```
npm install jquery jquery-ui
```

And then I've tried:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import jQuery from 'query';
import jQuery-ui from 'jquery-ui';
```

However jQuery UI does not seem to be imported when I try to do something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  $('ol#myList').selectable();
}
```

I believe the issue is with jQuery UI. What am I doing wrong? How can I get jQuery UI to work with this stack?

Thank you!

Comment: for starters, what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Where are you writing that line? It's likely the element isn't initialized yet so you should be using the `componentDidMount` callback

Comment: Can you try to `console.log($)` after you import `$`?

Comment: @ZekeDroid Sorry, it was in `componentDidMount()`, I edited my question.

Comment: @AlexPalcuie Please see my edits, I believe the issue is with jQuery UI, the `selectable()` function doesn't seem to work.

Comment: *"doesn't seem to work"* is not a proper problem description that anyone can troubleshoot from

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, please see my edit.

Comment: Again, what makes you think the issue is with jquery. Could you please please try giving us some console.logs? Do you get an error? Does nothing happen? what's expected? what went wrong?

Comment: you could try to `cnosole.log($.fn.selectable)` and see if it's underfined to ensure that it's not loading the jQuery UI

Comment: If you're using webpack, consider using `webpack-jquery-ui`

Answer (score 66):

I'm successfully using partial import from jquery-ui. I mean import to my module only what I needed from jquery-ui:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/theme.css';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/selectable.css';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/core';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/selectable';
```

( But take in account that I'm using webpack https://webpack.github.io/, in other environment approach may differ)

Comment: Using SystemJS/jspm, this approach works for me but requires adding '!' to the end of the css imports, e.g. `import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css!'`

Comment: Could you share your webpack.conf with us? I tried that with autocomplete `import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete';` and got `(0 , _jQuery2.default)(...).autocomplete is not a` in my browser. Also, webpack tells me a warning that there are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer, import core and then the widget you need! @muuvmuuv for me that is exactly what i did and does work :

import 'jquery-ui/ui/core';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete';

Comment: when using jquery-ui with webpack, any idea why it's not possible to import global functions like Sine, Circ, Elastic, Back, Bounce https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/effect.js#L932 ?? when I try to import, these functions are always undefined. I've tried different ways `import {Sine} from 'jquery-ui'` or `import {Sine} from 'jquery-ui/ui/effect'` - it is undefined in either case. I'm disappointed. Please advise.

Comment: @SemenShekhovtsov, try `import jquery_ui from 'jquery-ui'; console.log(jquery_ui.Sine); `

Comment: Depending on the version of jQuery, it might be just `import 'jquery-ui/selectable';`. Check exact path in `node_modules/jquery-ui`. Otherwise great answer, thanks.

Comment: If you're using webpack, consider using `webpack-jquery-ui`

Answer (score 17):

I first,

```
npm install jquery-ui-bundle --save
```

When I need it, I

```
import 'jquery-ui-bundle';
import 'jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.css';
```

Comment: Just to clarify `--save` includes the library since it is not being manually edited. If you need to modify anything with custom code you'd use `--save-dev`

Comment: "Bundle" means ready for webpack or other bundle tools. Right?
Anyway, this works for me.

Answer (score 14):

Add a alias in webpack config:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
  }
}
```

Save them in package.json:

```
npm i --save jquery
npm i --save jquery-ui-dist
```

Then

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
```

It work for me with the last jquery(3.2.1) and jquery-ui(1.12.1).

See my blog for detail: http://code.tonytuan.org/2017/03/webpack-import-jquery-ui-in-es6-syntax.html

Comment: I can't even begin to understand why they would have `jquery-ui` and `jquery-ui-dist` packages. I wasted so much time on this. Thanks for adding this answer!

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I think you can skip the `resolve` stage if you replace the last line with: `import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui;`

Comment: @haz - you often have to change your jquery build.  Pulling the entire jQuery lib in everytime is very taxing.  I can't recommend enough, using the `resolve` feature.  Otherwise you're hardcoding a specific dist into your code, that will probably change.

Comment: Well, not precisely. Skipping the `resolve` step gives up some syntactic sugar, but not much in this instance. In either case, it will still look for the version of JQuery as handled by `npm` and your `package.json` file and contained in your `node_modules` directory. This will update to the most recent, whenever you do `npm update`.

Answer (score 5):

component name is jqueryui (no hyphen), use `import jqueryui from 'jquery-ui'` 
or simply `import 'jquery-ui'`

Comment: When I try this, I get this error when I try to run: `can't execute file: /pathToRoot/bin/server.js
error given was: TypeError: Object function ( w ) {
if ( !w.document ) {
throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
}
return factory( w );
} has no method 'extend'
at uuid (/pathToRoot/node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:15:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/pathToRoot/node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js:316:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
(**See next comment for rest**)

Comment: at require.extensions.(anonymous function) (/pathToRoot/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:214:7)
at Object._module3.default._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/pathToRoot/node_modules/require-hacker/babel-transpiled-modules/require hacker.js:250:71)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.module._load (/pathToRoot/node_modules/piping/lib/launcher.js:32:16)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)`

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can share a simple project with minimal dependencies to reproduce the issue.

Comment: import jqueryui from 'jquery-ui' didn't work for me, but import 'jquery-ui' did

Answer (score 0):

Selectable is a plugin in JQuery UI. So we need to improt exact plugin from it. If you need selectable, then it would be like:

```
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/selectable'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [craigmichaelmartin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3670208/craigmichaelmartin)'s solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51271892/1510777.

Short version: Put the code into a file called `leaked-jquery.js' and import that instead of 'jquery'.

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
export default $;
export { jQuery };
```