# Buttonset and javascript error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-4

In my console I have this javascript error when the page is loaded:

> TypeError: $(...).buttonset is not a function
>   closeVariantForm
>   onclick

Is it possible to know where the problem is?

```
<p id="vstatus"><label for="variants_status">' . $this->app->getDef('text_status') . '</label>   On ' .  HTML::radioField('variants_status', 1) . '   Off ' .  HTML::radioField('variants_status', 0) . '</p>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#vstatus').buttonset();
});


function closeVariantForm() {
    $('#variantForm').hide();

    // reset fields
    $('#availableVariantsList').find(':checkbox:checked, :radio:checked').attr('checked', false);
    $('#availableVariantsList').find(':checkbox[id^=vg]').attr('disabled', true);

    $('#vstatus').buttonset('refresh');

    $('#variants_default').removeAttr('checked disabled');

    $('#variantListing').show();
    $('#formButtons').animate({'opacity': '1'}, 'fast').children().removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#sectionMenuContainer').animate({'opacity': '1'}, 'fast').children().removeAttr('disabled');
}
</script>
```

Comment: `.buttonset()` is not a native jQuery function, but rather one from jQuery UI. Have you remembered to import jQuery UI?

Comment: @ObsidianAge, ok, how to have the equivalent for jquery ?

Comment: You don't. If you want to use jQuery UI functionality, you import jQuery UI.

Comment: @ObsidianAge: I use jquery and boostrap4, not ui jquery, is possible to translate this point ?

Comment: It's literally one line of code that you import, like you import jQuery: `https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js`. Just import that after you import jQuery.

Comment: @ObsidianAge: No I don't want include ui jquery that's why I would know if there is an equivalent code

Comment: jQuery UI is only 248 kilobytes. You could perhaps look at the [**documentation**](https://api.jqueryui.com/buttonset/) for `buttonset`, and build your own equivalent. But considering jQuery UI is maintained by a professional team whose job is to make jQuery UI as compatible and easy to use as possible, you'd be **far** better off simply importing jQuery UI (or not using `buttonset` at all).

Comment: Code Snippet? Testable example?

Answer (score 0):

The error is at `$('#vstatus').buttonset();`  You're calling a method that doesn't exist on vanilla jQuery.  Looks like you're trying to use a method on the jquery-ui extension.  Are you including this extension in the page?

If you're loading the jquery-ui library, you'll need to make sure that this dependency is loaded before attempting to use any of the methods that this decorates jquery with, otherwise you'll get `Type Error`s, like this one.

Comment: I use jquery and boostrap4, not ui jquery, is possible to translate this point ?

Comment: If you're asking how to include this lib, [you can read the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/)

Answer (score -1):

From looking at the discussion in this post it looks to me like you need to install jQuery-ui. You have three ways of doing this that I was able to find quickly

1) **CDN**

Include the following line in your php file:
`<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` Here's the link for where that is : [link to jQuery-UI cdn](https://code.jquery.com/ui/)

2) **Download and link**

Download the library, unzip it and link it to your php file in a similar fashion to how you linked jQuery and bootstrap.

3) **Install for ES6/7**

I highly doubt that you're using these but in case you are you will need to make use of import to bring it into your project. There is a related post on that here: [How to import jQuery UI using ES6/ES7 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259835/how-to-import-jquery-ui-using-es6-es7-syntax)

**NOTE**
Make sure to include jQuery BEFORE you include jQuery UI, it has a dependency on jQuery.