# How do I use "draggable()" function in React?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, es6-class

In my React code, I'm trying to convert **createClass** into **ES6 Classes**, and I'm struggling here:

```
componentDidMount()
{
$(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).draggable();
}
```

(which used to be:
  `$(this.getDOMNode()).draggable();`
before conversion, and worked perfectly)

The error I'm getting is:

> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_react_dom___default.a.findDOMNode(...).draggable is not a function

[image]

I'm aware that draggable() is a function in jQuery UI, so I tried importing that in the script tag of my HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I've included the following in my React file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery'; 
import css from './style.css';
```

Nothing seems to work whatsoever.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `react-native`, right?

Comment: As you said `draggable` is jquery plugin. So you need jquery instance to use it. Why did you remove `$(...node)`?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Oh sorry the $ sign got left behind while copying. I have updated the code here, and the problem still persists.

Comment: Yes, I'm creating an app using the 'create-react-app' command in terminal.

Comment: The error message should be different then :). Also make sure you are correctly importing jquery-ui module as well. `jquery.fn.draggable` should be a function.

Comment: Oh yes, it's showing:
`TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jquery___default(...)(...).draggable is not a function`
now. Help me out please?

Comment: Check you have imported jquery-ui. There should be `import 'jquery-ui'` line of code. This question might be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259835/how-to-import-jquery-ui-using-es6-es7-syntax

Comment: I just wanted to say, this is my first time using this website after having signed up for more than 2 years. If everybody here is as helpful as you, I'm never getting off it. Thank you so much :)
Also, how do I upvote your answer so that other noobs like me could see?

Comment: I've posted an answer. You could accept it if it was helpfull :)

Comment: Done, and done. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments.

You still need to wrap DOM node with jQuery instance to use jquery plugins on it.

```
componentDidMount() {
  // $() is important
  $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).draggable();
}
```

You need to import jquery-ui module to enhance jQuery prototype with `draggable`, `sortable` and other jQueryUI plugins.

```
import 'jquery-ui';
```