# Imported jQuery plugin, using ES6 syntax, doesn't see jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, ecmascript-6

I've follow answer from this question: [How to import jquery using ES6 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34340392/387194)

I have this code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
import 'jquery.terminal';
```

but got error `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` from the plugin, how to resolve this?

Comment: From what file do you use this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue using:

```
require('jquery.terminal');
```