# npm with jquery doesn't work with import?

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm

I manage to run my app if I remove bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min.js. Not sure why the jquery isn't load with npm, below is my code.

[image]

I tried import $ from 'jquery'; which is an accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax), but still couldn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried import $ from 'jquery'; but still getting the same error.

Comment: Some helpful hints to getting an answer to your question: 1) never post images of code, always copy/paste the actual code, 2) show the actual error (also not in image form), 3) keep your question updated with your current status (make sure not to change it to a different question in the process).  If the issue from the linked question isn't helping, in which way is it not helping?  What is the error message that you mention?  Updating your question may help get you the answer that you need.