# Can't import both `$` and `jQuery` in one line in ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to practice using ES6 syntax, and I wanted to try using ES6 with *jQuery* and *Webpack*. I read [a StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax) illustrating how, and down below there was a comment saying why not just do

```
import {$, jQuery} from 'jquery'
```

I tried, and I'm getting an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , r.$) is not a function`. When I simply separate the two using two import statements, the error goes away. Any idea why? Is the one line import statement invalid? If so, how come?

Comment: Have you tried using webpack ProvidePlugin? :  `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
})`

Comment: jquery only exports $... the answer you reference is actually wrong in his example `$` and `jquery` are the same thing

Comment: Try doing `import $, jQuery from 'jquery'` so that it gives the default import two names.

Comment: `import $, * as jQuery from "jquery";`? Or if they are both defaults `import $, jQuery from "jquery";`?

Comment: @AndrésAndrade what do you mean? I've only been learning React with Webpack so I'm unaware of the ProvidePlugin feature. Would that go in my `webpack.config.js` file?
@Maxwelll got it, thank you! @4castle @Andrew Li I can't do `import $, jQuery from 'jquery'` as that results in `unexpected token` error when compiling. I think the lesson learned here is that jquery only exports `$`.

Comment: @Sticky Exactly. This way you can make a module available as a variable in every module so you don't have to import it every time https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#plugin-provideplugin

Comment: @AndrésAndrade oh awesome! thanks, I will take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import X from 'thing';
```

is short for

```
import {default as X} from 'thing';
```

which means if you want to import the default as both `$` and `jQuery`, you need to do

```
import {default as $, default as jQuery} from 'jquery';
```

Note, `jquery` exports only `$` and doing the above only aliases jquery as two different names. Also, be sure to checkout Webpack's ProvidePlugin feature.

Comment: none of above worked for me.. ERROR Module .../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js does not export default
this works `import * as jQuery from 'jquery';`

Comment: Perhaps you have something in your webpack config that is breaking that behavior? It definitely works.