# Include bootstrap features into a custom vuejs component

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm asked to add a new html page to a [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs) project. This page is already fully developed and is based on [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and some [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) features.

I've created a new component.

**newPage.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="my-new-page">
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<style src="path/to/_bootstrap.scss" lang="scss" scoped></style>
<style src="path/to/font-awesome.scss" lang="scss" scoped></style>
<style src="path/to/animate.css" scoped></style>
<style src="path/to/custom/css.css" scoped></style>


<script src="path/to/custom/js.js"></script>
```

**js.js**

```
   import jQuery from 'jquery';
   // Same error even with window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
   import collapse from 'path/to/bootstrap/feature/collapse.js";

   export default {
       created() {
           runjQuery(jQuery);
       },
   };

   function runjQuery($) {
       // here is how I thought integrate the jquery script of the new html page
       $(function () {
            ....
            $('#navbar').collapse('hide');
       });
   }
```

But this obviously does not work because `collapse.js` cannot access `jQuery` and I get this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

How do I fix this problem?

Given that I don't want (if possible) to add bootstrap and jquery globally to my project because this will surely breaks here and there in my other components?

Comment: Have you taken a look at vue-strap? https://wffranco.github.io/vue-strap/

Comment: @enriqg9 there are not all the features I need, collapse for instance

Comment: I suspect you need the bracketed form of `import`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43546877/392102

Comment: @RoyJ I have no problem Injecting jquery, the problem is when injecting bootsrap which depends on jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, `require` works while [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) does not.

```
 // Declare $ and jQuery globally into my whole app :(
 window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
 // this does not work
 // import collapse from 'path/to/bootstrap/feature/collapse.js";
 require('path/to/bootstrap/feature/collapse.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that jQuery isn't already loaded. Loading it twice might cause some issues. Remove your jquery import and maybe check in `console.log($)` if they've built it on jQuery chances are it's already there.
2. If 1. fails you have to import jQuery in you main js file or to import it globally.