# Getting type error importing jQuery using ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Following the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax) question I tried to import jQuery using `import {$, jQuery} from 'jquery';`. and am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery.$) is not a function` in the browser.
Am using Babel with the ES2015 preset to transpile my Code. If I use two separate imports i.e. `import $ from 'jquery'; import jQuery from 'jquery'` then it works fine. Why can't I use the combined syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `import $ from 'jQuery'` is short for `import {default as $} from 'jQuery'`. If you import `{$, jQuery}`, those are two names that are not exported. You can however use

```
import {
    default as $,
    default as jQuery
} from 'jQuery';
```