# How to import jQuery from a file using es6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Due to this project idiosyncrasies I need to import `jQuery` into my `main.js` using a direct path that is not in the **node_modules** folder but I am not able to do it. All the questions I have found points to `jquery` that lives in `node_modules`

I have this

```
import {MyModule} from './components/myModule.js';
import jQuery from './jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js';
```

`MyModule` works as expected (on Chrome) but jQuery yields:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'default'

jquery-3.3.1.js is the [uncompressed, development jQuery 3.3.1](https://jquery.com/download/) version from jQuery.com, I have also tried with the production version.

How should I import it?

Edit:

This is **NOT** a duplicate of [How to import jquery using ES6 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax). Because `import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';` searches on `node_modules` and when I import it from the given path I get the error quoted above.

Comment: Try `import './jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js';` only. To import something `from` it, jQuery would need to use ES6 module syntax

Comment: Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax

Comment: why not use jquery npm package and then `import $ from "jquery";`

Comment: @Bergi you were right! Thanks.

Comment: @newman no it is not. That and other questions/answers points always to `node_modules`.

Comment: @EduLomeli sadly this project should always be available over internet when on develop with a list of the files used. It is a really weird thing that I do not like but I HAVE to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import jquery using ES6 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax)

Comment: @distante Are you using Webpack?

Comment: @amedina I am testing it first directly on Chrome (that allows imports) and then using [rollupJs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) for the production version.

Comment: @Bergi had the only answer that worked across so many SO topics, comments, and and other internet searches. As other people noted, most people want it to be in NPM, but when you have just the standalone file, Bergi's is the one that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ES6 import like:

`import * as jQuery from './jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js'`

Documentation about the import statement:
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/import

If you are not using ES6, you can use @Bergi solution given in the comments of the question :

`import './jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js';`

Comment: I just get 'jQuery is not a function' when I try to use this syntax with jQuery 3.6.0

Comment: I got the same error as above. Not sure why this is an accepted answer

Comment: I get the same  'jQuery is not a function'  @GregPettit, did you find a solution?

Comment: @VAAA It's been a while, but I commented in the original question that another commenter, Bergi, had a working syntax. Sadly, his "answer" is only in the form of a comment! But May 19's version of Greg believed that it worked.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me.

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "@popperjs/core"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
import jQuery from "jquery"
window.jQuery = jQuery
window.$ = jQuery

$(document).on("turbo:load", () => {
    console.log("turbo!");
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
    const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))
});
```