# Bundling JS files (webpack)

Tags: webpack, import, require

Which one to choose with webpack:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

or

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

and how to import or require a file that does not have anything to export as such (only helpers functions)?

Also is `var $ =` mandatory when using the `require('jquery');` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you're using `babel-loader`  or not.

If you don't want to write in ECMA6+/JSX syntax, you are browser-safe to go with older CommonJS/node.js `require('jquery');` syntax.

If you're want to support newer syntaxes like ECMA6, ECMAscript-2015, ECMA7, JSX etc., you'd probably want to go with `babel-loader` and ECMA6 `import syntax`. Be careful about import [default vs named vs alias vs wildcard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) import though, you might want to use syntaxes:

```
import {jQuery as $} from 'jquery';
```

or

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

More on ways to import jquery [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax).

If you don't want to import any particular name from the module (e.g. if you import `jQuery` just to let it adds itself to global `window.jQuery = window.$`), you can just say `import 'jquery';`.

To enable `babel-loader` in webpack, use configuration like:

`webpack.config.js`

```
  {
    entry: 'app.js',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      publicPath: publicPath,
      filename: outputFilename
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
        $: 'jquery', 
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      })
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
            plugins: ['transform-es2015-destructuring', 'transform-object-rest-spread']
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    ...
   }
 }
```

Note also that you can use [webpack ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/), as I did in this config to shim jQuery for modules that expect it available as a global variable.

Comment: and how to import / require files that do not have anything to export as such apart from having helpers functions?

Comment: @lovemyjob Just say `import 'helper.js';` or `require('helper.js');` :)