# React - jquery module not found

Tags: jquery, reactjs, npm

I have loaded jquery via the npm, and I am trying to import jQuery in App.js of my React app like so:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

But it says:

*Module not found: Can't resolve 'jquery'*

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: do you need to put something in front of jquery like `js/jquery` or `node-modules/jquery`?

Comment: also, have you looked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't come up with a solution however doing an *nmp install* fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

You should install jQuery via npm or yarn.

```
npm install -S jquery

yarn add jquery
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't help.

Comment: Also note you have to import jquery in every file you plan on using it in.