# "$.getJSON is not a function" using jQuery from babel-node and ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import jQuery using ES6, and, most importantly, **I'm running the code using babel-node (cli).**

I've read [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax), but the solution reported there doesn't seem to work: I tried

```
npm i --save jquery
```

and then

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';

console.log($);
```

But I get `undefined` logged to the console, and I cannot use jQuery.

**How should  I import `$`?**

I also tried

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

as suggested from @Jai and reported on the [npm manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery#babel), but even though I obtain "[Function"] as the result of `console.log($)`, `$.getJSON("www.google.com")` returns me `TypeError: _jquery2.default.getJSON is not a function`.

This is true only running the code from babel-node (cli), if I run the code from the browser loading the generated bundle it works.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax

Comment: Have you tried the actual syntax from the question? `import * as $ from 'jquery';` If you write `import { $, JQuery }`, you try to destructure the object the jquery file returns, which isn't correct I think. Also, $ and JQuery are the same function.

Comment: Checkout the npm package [how to import jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery#babel)

Comment: @Shilly Trying import * as $ from 'jquery'; and then using $.getJSON("http://www.google.com"); gives me TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? If you are using jQuery slim $.getJSON is not part of the interface which is why you'd see that error. It doesn't package $.ajax or the helper methods.

Comment: @dysfunc npm tells me jquery is 3.3.1, and I think it is the full version of the library. I also tried $.get but it doesn't work either.

Comment: what do you have in your package.json for jQuery?

Comment: @dysfunc    "jquery": "^3.3.1". However I've just tried running the code from the browser using the generated bundle and it works, it doesn't work running it from cli with babel-node, maybe I'll update my question

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try using the code below

`import $ from 'jquery';`

or

`import jQuery from 'jquery';`

Comment: I tried the first solution. console.log says "[Function]", but $.getJSON("http://www.google.com"); gives me TypeError: _jquery2.default.getJSON is not a function