# “$.get is not a function” using jQuery from babel-node

Tags: javascript, jquery, command-line, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm running the following code from a test.js file using **babel-node** from the command line: `babel-node test.js`

installing jquery

```
npm i --save jquery
```

test.js:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$.get("www.google.com");
```

I get `TypeError: _jquery2.default.get is not a function`

Any suggestion?

Please note that this question is not a duplicate of [How to import jquery using ES6 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax), because this seems a problem specific to babel-node (the same code works if I create a bundle using webpack with babel and run it from a browser)

Answer (score 0):

Your import should be `import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Also it most likely a conflict of `$`. Try adding

```
 var jq = $.noConflict();
 jq.get("www.google.com");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I keep getting TypeError: $.get is not a function

Comment: Its most likely a conflict issue, add `$.noConflict();` in script tag, Read more here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Unfortunately I get TypeError: _jquery2.default.noConflict is not a function

Answer (score 0):

To get it it work with NodeJS, jQuery must be executed in dom context. Modules like domJS can do the job othewise if you need making ajax request. The best choice is using other specific modules like "https" or "request" like the example bellow :

```
import https from 'https';
https.get("https://www.google.com");
```