# Is my jquery import slowing down create-react-app bundle time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app project with many components and they import jquery using ES6 modules as below.

`import $ from 'jquery'`

The current build time is about 8 minutes and I feel it's because of jquery.

Did anyone face this before? If so what is the best way to use jquery in create-react-app

Comment: I can't see an 83Kb file making that much difference. The only way to be sure is to test it. Remove your references and build again.

Comment: Maybe its the eslint with jquery that might be causing this? I will try to check without importing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `jquery` in react apps is undesirable because `react` is *declarative* and `jquery` is 100% imperative. It makes code less maintainable and readable. Also it makes hard to test your components. If you use jquery for ajax you can replace it for example with axios.

Comment: We are not using this for ajax requests. We use it for few  jquery helpers. Eventually we want to move away from jquery but it is a huge change for us as it is used in all the components. So we want to know the best way to import it.

Comment: While true, this is all completely irrelevant to the OP's issue of loading times.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax