# How can i import a javascript library that does not use namespace in into a namespace without editing the file library is in?

Tags: javascript

I need to use these javascript functions inside this file. Said functions are not in a namespace. I dont want to edit that file. How can i import the functions into a namespace in a different file? Preferably without using any third party library.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax

Comment: *these javascript functions* - which ones?

Comment: @Jaromanda X: All the functions in the file.

Comment: which file? you mean any arbitrary library? you can't change how a library works without changing the library

Answer (score 0):

Say you have `header.js` (may be a library) which has

```
export {
    funcA,
    funcB,
    funcC,
    ...
}
```

In another file (may be your file) `user.js` (assume it is in the same folder), you can write

```
import * from "./header.js"
```

Then in `user.js`, you can use
`funcA`, `funcB`, `funcC` and any other functions that `header.js` exports.

And to avoid name conflict, you can write

```
import * as header from "./header.js"
```

Then in `user.js`, you can use
`header.funcA` ...

Is this you need?

Comment: No, functions are not exported at all.