# I want to delete a post (data) from the database and got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Tags: express, mongoose, http-delete

I have these in my layout.ejs

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My main.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.delete-article').on('click', function(e) {
    $target = $(e.target);
    const id = $target.atrr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/post/'+id,
        success: function(response) {
            alert('Deleting Post');
            window.location.href='/';
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
}) 
})
```

and these is my delete link

```
<a class="delete-article" href="#" data-id="{item._id}">Delete</a>
```

I have installed jQuery

```
 npm install jquery
```

index.js file

```
router.delete( '/post/:id', function( req, res ){

let query = {_id:req.params.id}

  Post.remove(query, function(err) {
    if(err){
    console.log(err);
    }
   res.send('Success');
});
});
```

I am getting the error `main.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` whenever I refresh my browser without even clicking on delete link.

I know this is a problem from jQuery but I decided to post all my codes to make it easier for someone to help. I started learning Nodejs and Express one month ago.

Comment: You did not import $ from your jquery library before use. Your question is similar to this one. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34338411

Comment: Thank you so much, i got it working now  by doing exactly what you said.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import jquery using ES6 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax)