# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when importing function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got the following script that works fine as is:

eventslist.bundle.js

```
// import {
//     equalheight,
// } from './functions';

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

    /**
     * Will ensure that all elements are of equal height 
     * @param {DOMElem} selector 
     */
    const equalheight = (selector) => {

        var currentTallest = 0,
            currentRowStart = 0,
            rowDivs = new Array(),
            $el,
            topPosition = 0;
        $(selector).each(function () {
            ...
```

However, when I move this function into the functions.js file, and uncomment the import statement:

functions.js

```
import {$} from 'jquery';

/**
 * Will ensure that all elements are of equal height 
 * @param {DOMElem} selector 
 */
export const equalheight = (selector) => {

    var currentTallest = 0,
        currentRowStart = 0,
        rowDivs = new Array(),
        $el,
        topPosition = 0;
    $(selector).each(function () {
```

And then update my bundle script:

eventslist.bundle.js

```
import {
    equalheight,
} from './functions';

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

    // /**
    //  * Will ensure that all elements are of equal height 
    //  * @param {DOMElem} selector 
    //  */
    // const equalheight = (selector) => {

    //     var currentTallest = 0,
    //         currentRowStart = 0,
    //         rowDivs = new Array(),
    //         $el,
    //         topPosition = 0;
    //     $(selector).each(function () {
```

I get an error on the `$(selector).each(function () {` line telling me that

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

I'd like to remove this function from the script so it's re-usable. But what am I doing wrong? jQuery is a NPM dependency and from what I've read, this is how to import it.

Comment: `Will ensure that all elements are of equal height` you don't need JS for that. CSS Flexbox does it out of the box. `display:flex; align-items:stretch;` job done

Comment: Also, why not simply import jQuery in your index.html? `<script src=".../jquery.js">`

Comment: Thanks. I've used a <script> tag as you suggest which kinda makes sense anyway as I can load it from CDN. Yeh works now. I'll explore the flex option too. I'm using isotope which does it's own  positioning anyway, perhaps I can find a CSS solution to the height thing instead. Can't recall now why I opted for JS, it's been there a while.

Comment: Possibly because I'm using boostrap columns and it's those i need to resize, maybe I didn't see the option in bootstrap itself and defaulted to JS instead. I should have explored the CSS options first I guess :)

Comment: Implicit dependencies are a really bad idea in module development. I highly advise against including jQuery as a global, undocumented dependency.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the different version of jquery and npm has different import way.

Accroding to [How to import jquery using ES6 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax)

I think you can try ways as follows：

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

or

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

And I suggest that you can use console.log to observe what you really imported.

Answer (score 0):

Import your jQuery with

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```