# TypeError: jquery_1.default.getJSON is not a function

Tags: jquery, node.js, typescript, backend

I get the error above when trying to do:

```
const data = await $.getJSON(raw.data.data.uri, // Get metadata from uri
    function (data: any) {
        return data;
    }
);
```

I imported jQuery like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

I am doing this in my nodeJs backend. In the reactJs front end it somehow worked without any problems.

I am using Typescript in both frontend and backend.

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import jquery using ES6 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax)