# I want to import bootstrap js and jquery js file in astro js

Tags: javascript, node.js, astrojs

I tried ES imports statements and normal script tag to import the required JS file and CSS file for bootstrap in astro js project

I am getting this Issue.

> Error: The following dependencies are imported but could not be
> resolved:
>
> js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js (imported by
> /media/****li/hdd/***ed-astro/src/layouts/main.astro)   js/bootstrap.js
> (imported by /media/****li/hdd/***ed-astro/src/layouts/main.astro)   js/custom.js
> (imported by /media/****li/hdd/***ed-astro/src/layouts/main.astro)
>
> Are they installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, in the main layout file - I had to rectify the file path

From

```
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

TO

```
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

same for all CSS file ..

all these assets were places in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to set `type="text/javascript"`
It wasn't working till I added that.

Comment: Adding `type="text/javascript"` works because Astro treats it the same as `is:inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [craigmichaelmartin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3670208/craigmichaelmartin)'s solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51271892/1510777.

Short version: Add a jQuery loader module using the code below, and import that instead of 'jquery'.

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
export default $;
export { jQuery };
```