# jQuery is not defined in next.js

Tags: jquery, reactjs, next.js

I installed jquery and dependencies through the terminal like:

```
npm i jquery --save
```

And import jquery in  a component like :

```
import $ from "jquery"
```

But when I run the project. it throws an error:

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Who can I fix it?

**Edit**

here is a component file called animate component:

```
import jQuery from "jquery";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
import "jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-shake";

function animate() {
  $(".addToCart").on("click", function () {
    var cart = $(".fa-shopping-cart");
    var btn = $(this);
    if (btn) {
      var imgclone = btn
        .clone()
        .offset({
          top: btn.offset().top,
          left: btn.offset().left,
        })
        .css({
          opacity: "0.8",
          position: "absolute",
          float: "right",
          height: "40px",
          width: "250px",
          "z-index": "100",
        })
        .appendTo($("body"))
        .animate(
          {
            top: cart.offset().top + 10,
            left: cart.offset().left + 10,
            width: 250,
            height: 40,
          },
          500,
          "easeInOutExpo"
        );

      imgclone.animate(
        {
          width: 0,
          height: 0,
        },
        function () {
          $(this).detach();
        }
      );
    }
  });
}
export default animate;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import jquery using ES6 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax) This answer should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42175610/2226755

Comment: Oh yes, Answer my question in a post format to add reputation if you would. tnx and regards

Comment: In this case I will get more `-1` because I will copy/paste an answer of duplicate question

Comment: unfortunately when I refresh a page error occurred:ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: Can you share your files code ?

Comment: Please check the edit section of the current post