# ReferenceError: $ is not defined, Jquery Import with vite

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vite

I tried with fresh install laravel 9.20 and with minimum configuration

**in vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

**in app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';

import $ from "jquery"; 
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

import '../sass/app.scss';
```

i have tried with this too

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

load the assets in blade and i test with this script

```
@vite(['resources/js/app.js']);

$("#alertbox").alert("test");
```

but i get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I can't make it work, please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import jquery using ES6 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This happens because of Vite's module loading order. You're seeing a race condition, and it's not an issue with the import.

To confirm this, try calling the jQuery code after a timeout as below.

```
<script>
   setTimeout(function() {
      console.log($);
      $("#alertbox").alert("test");
   }, 5000);
</script>
```

If there's no error with the above, then it means the code is getting executed in the incorrect order. But adding a timeout is not a good way to solve it, so let's look at the cause of the problem.

If you look at source code you'll see something like this.

```
<script type="module" src="http://localhost/build/assets/app.342432.js"></script>
```

This means Vite is loading scripts as modules. And [module scripts are always deferred](https://javascript.info/modules-intro#module-scripts-are-deferred). So if your jQuery script is placed after Vite directive, jQuery code is executed first, before loading jQuery to window - this triggers `$ is undefined` error.

In best practise, you should move the jQuery code to `app.js` file, so it stays in it's own module. The other way to handle this is to mark your script tag as a module, then it'll follow the loading order of the document.

Change the script tag as below.

```
@vite(['resources/js/app.js']);

<script type="module">
   $("#alertbox").alert("test");
</script>
```

Comment: adding `type="module"` solved the issue. thanks

Comment: I would suggest the person who posted this question to mark this answer as correct. It really helped!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I was wondering why I was getting the error despite setting things up correctly. I struggled for days with this error and I'm glad you curated this solution and explanation.

Answer (score 6):

add type = module in tag script

```
<script type="module">
    code....
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue while generating DataTable using jquery datatable plugins with vite in laravel 10, fixed by

1. Assigning $ to the window object in app.js
2. Adding module in script declaration.

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = $; // this worked for me
import 'datatables.net';
```

**resources/views/users/index.blade.php**

```
<script type="module">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#websites-table').DataTable({
            // Your code
        });       
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

add jquery from cdn in the blade template

> https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

and solve it

Comment: Some people are using webpack or vite, so this solution is probably not relevant.