# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined - Laravel 9, Vite

Tags: jquery, laravel, import, vite

I'm trying to import jQuery in my Laravel 9 project, which I installed with `npm i jquery`

I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

in my `app.blade.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>
```

in my another view, which extends `app.blade.php`

```
<script>
  $(function(){
      alert('jquery ok');
  })
</script>
```

in `resources/js/app.js`

I tried all sorts of things

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

```
import $ from 'jquery';

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

```
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';

export default {
    plugins: [
        // Add it first
        inject({
            $: 'jquery',
        }),
        // Other plugins...
    ],
    // The rest of your configuration...
};
```

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
} catch (e) {}
```

Nothing works. How can I fix this?

npm - 8.11.0
node - 16.16.0
laravel/framework - 9.32.0
vite - 3.14

Comment: See this; https://devdojo.com/thinkverse/how-to-use-jquery-with-laravel-and-vite

Comment: @Snapey thank you. but it did not help me solve the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: $ is not defined, Jquery Import with vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73010251/referenceerror-is-not-defined-jquery-import-with-vite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to my question was to be found here [ReferenceError: $ is not defined, Jquery Import with vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73010251/referenceerror-is-not-defined-jquery-import-with-vite)

```
<script type="module"> //type="module" is the important part
    $(function () {
        alert('jquery ok');
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you importing your JQuery files? (JS and CSS)

You need something like this on your head section: *(obviously you have to specify your actual path to those files)*

```
<link href="./jquery-files/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="./jquery-files/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-files/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then you just need to use a script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $().ready(function () {
        //add all JQuery related code here!!
        alert('jquery ok'); //this will show an alert when the page is loaded
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use javascript **dynamic imports** because some pages may not require jQuery.

Build tools/bundlers like *ViteJs*, *WebPack*, *Laravel Mix* and others support this.

Inside your `app.js`

```
async function main() {
  const { default: jQuery } = await import('jquery')
  window.jquery = window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;

  // code that uses jQuery
  console.log('jQuery v', $().jquery);
}

main();
```

You could put the import in side an if statement

```
async function main() {

  if (document.querySelector('.useJquery')) {
    const { default: jQuery } = await import('jquery')
    window.jquery = window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;

    // code that uses jQuery
    console.log('jQuery v', $().jquery);
  }
}
```

In any page that requires jQuery you could add `class="useJquery"`.

Then only pages with the `useJquery` class will download JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was on how the libraries are imported on the `bootstrap.js`. I changed the file:

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
// Since I'm using jquery from admin-lte  
import $ from 'admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery';
import * as Popper from 'popper.js';
// Since I'm using jquery from admin-lte  
import 'admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap'
window._ = _;
window.Popper = Popper.defaults;
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

Now you can use

```html
<script type="module">
    $(function () {
        console.log('Jquery loaded');    
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this article](https://devdojo.com/thinkverse/how-to-use-jquery-with-laravel-and-vite) to install & setup jQuery in Laravel 9:

Install jQuery

```
npm install jquery --save-dev
```

Import jQuery through bootstrap
This needs to be just after lodash import

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
```

In the blade file

```
<script type="module">
    $('body').html('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');
</script>
```

App build:

```
npm run build
```