# I have a problem Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'magnificPopup')

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-mix, magnific-popup

I have a problem Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'magnificPopup'). I use Laravel mix and jquery v3.7.0
this is my code
app.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = window.$ = $

import 'magnific-popup';
$('.popup-image').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });
```

I tried

```
import 'magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import jquery using ES6 syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45224057/283366)

Comment: I get an error when I import the magnific-popup library, I still use jquery normally