# Javascript addEventListener not reading resize

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Hi I'm trying to add an eventListener where it adds an h1 tag with the width and height of the browser when your resize it. I don't understand why it's not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Window size</title>


</head>


<body>

<div id="wh"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

"use strict";

document.addEventListener("onresize", function(){

 var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
 var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

 document.getElementById('wh').innerHTML = "<h1>Width: " + width + "  Height: " + height + "</h1>";

});


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: window.addEventListener("resize", ...

Comment: ^^ + `document` doesn't trigger `resize` event, only `window`will.

Comment: Use `window.addEventListener('resize', func)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    document.getElementById('wh').innerHTML = "<h1>Width: " + width + "  Height: " + height + "</h1>";
};
```

instead on document.addEventListener and otherwise it's the event "resize" and not "onresize"

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong event, it needs to be simply 'resize'. See here for further examples - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Window size</title>


</head>


<body>

<div id="wh"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

"use strict";

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){

 var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
 var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

 document.getElementById('wh').innerHTML = "<h1>Width: " + width + "  Height: " + height + "</h1>";

});


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick help, I'm just learning java script and this was a practice exercise. What's the difference between document and window?

Comment: Stackoverflow knows all, and its explained here much better than I ever will - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript