# Listening to scroll event on window vs. on document leads to conflict between handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Is there any difference between those two?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() { /**/ });
```

and

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() { /**/ });
```

**The reason I'm asking** is that I've noticed that if I have 2 handlers (one listening on `window` and the second on `document`) and at some point I will `return false;` in the `document` one, the `window` handler stops firing, even if the event is namespaced.

You can see the behavior **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/q1ogem9b/)**. After you scroll beyond 300px from the top, the `window` handler's count doesn't increase anymore.

If I change the `window` selector to `document`, the conflict doesn't occur.

And the Fiddle code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed">
  <div>document scroll event: <span class="scroll1">0</span></div>
  <div>window scroll event: <span class="scroll2">0</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    var $scroll1 = $('.scroll1');
    var $scroll2 = $('.scroll2');

    function updateCount($el) {
        $el.text(parseInt($el.text(), 10) + 1);
    }

    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        updateCount($scroll1);
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        updateCount($scroll2);
    });
});
```

Comment: `document` event triggers before `window` event but you are `returning false` in the `document` event so why would you expect the `window` event to trigger?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript

Comment: @Nope Do you mean the `document` event fires before `window` *in my code* or generally this is how browsers handle JS in this case? If I swap the order of the event handlers in my example -- nothing changes.

Comment: @lesssugar Test it. do `$(window).on('click', function(){console.log('window-click');})` - `$(document).on('click', function(){console.log('document-click');})` and see what happens. Add `return false` to the document event and see the result. It's how it is. Stick with `document` or `window` I suppose.

Comment: Majority of people will use window to attach listeners for scroll and resize

Comment: @Nope Yep, of course, I see what you're saying. Click on `documents` returns `false`, thus preventing event propagation up. I thought I could resolve this using namespaced events, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 23):

Events bubble

what you have is

```
window
  |
  v
document
  |
  v
body
```

This is how the events are handled

> 1. user scrolls on body
> 2. Event scroll is triggered on `body`
> 3. check event handlers
>      3.1. if any event handler on `body` returns false stop here
>      3.2. if no event handlers registered or all event handlers return true, null or undefined pass scroll event to parent(document, goto step 4)
> 4. Event scroll is triggered on `document`
> 5. check event handlers
>      5.1. if any event handler on `document` returns false stop here
>      5.2. if no event handlers registered or all event handlers return true, null or undefined pass scroll event to parent(window goto step 6)
> 6. Event scroll is triggered on `window`
> 7. check event handlers
>      7.1. if any event handler on `window` returns false stop here
>      7.2. if no event handlers registered or all event handlers return true, null or undefined call other event handlers that come after this one.

You can see where the break points are at #.1
If any of those return false the entire bubble sequense is halted. it's like an emergency brake on a train. Not only your cart stops where you are scoped/positioned, but the entire train stops.