# what is and where is DOM relation between DOM and Window?

Tags: jquery, dom, window

Can some one show me the graphical representation of DOM and window, basically in browser where will be the DOM and windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks Ravenouss for sharing the link........

Answer (score 1):

Think about it like this :

What's your operating system ?

Your operating system is a program that is loaded when you start the computer up. It provides a way for other programs to access the speakers, keyboard, screen, hard drives and network card in your computer. Your operating system loads applications and then lets those applications access the rest of the computer.

That's the relationship between the web browser window and the DOM (document object model). The DOM is like the OS of the Web Browser. It loads scripts and then gives the scripts access to the parts of the browser.

Some people make a distinction between the Document object model (DOM) and the [Browser object model](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp) (BOM)
But in my years of experience, I've heard both referred to by the same term : DOM.