# *.pageYOffset, *.scrollY, *.scrollTop always logging undefined

Tags: javascript

My JS needs to know how far the user is scrolled down the page.

If I run this code:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', event => console.log(document.pageYOffset));
```

...or do the same thing with scrollY ... or scrollTop ... or swap 'document' in for 'window' ... the console *hears* the event as I scroll, but always logs 'undefined'. This happens across multiple HTML documents, in Chrome and Firefox, whether I have any CSS reset on or not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: these properties are on `window`, not `document`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's `window.pageYOffset` not `document.pageYOffset`. Refer [What is the difference between window, screen, and document in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895202/what-is-the-difference-between-window-screen-and-document-in-javascript#:%7E:text=window%20is%20the%20execution%20context,the%20physical%20display%27s%20full%20screen)