# alert Panotour Pro panorama name in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve a panorama name in javascript from a virtual tour output by PanoTour Pro.

[image: Panorama Properties]

I'm just trying to retrieve the name, circled here.  Using alert() as an example would be fine, and then I'm good from there.

Comment: alert(get(scene[get(xml.scene)].title));
alert(get(scene[0].name));
alert(scene.title.name);
alert(scene.name);
alert(scene.title);
alert(xml.scene.name);
alert(xml.scene.title);
alert(xml.scene.title.name);

Comment: You may use Chrome dev tools and info from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934787/view-list-of-all-javascript-variables-in-google-chrome-console

Comment: I don't know what to search for.

Comment: You can list your global variables from the link above, then the property you are looking for is a member of one of those, or their children...

Comment: Why must I use Chrome? The javascript debugger is the same exact one in Safari.  What is the property I am looking for? I don't know. I searched 'scene' which returns nothing.

Comment: Just found out there's no way to access that. I'll have to wait for the next version of PanoTour Pro.