# JavaScript: is it possible to get the content of the current namespace?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

As the question suggests — is it possible to get the names of all variables declared in the current namespace? For example, something like this:

```
>>> var x = 42;
>>> function bar() { ...}
>>> getNamespace()
{ x: 42, bar: function(){} }
>>>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope, although with different wording.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible in most implementations. Though in Rhino, you can reach to the activation object via `__parent__`.

```
js> function f(){ var x,y=1; return (function(){}).__parent__ }
js> uneval([v for(v in Iterator(f()))])
[["arguments", {}], ["x", , ], ["y", 1]]
```

For details, see http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-2-variable-object/.

Answer (score 0):

```
function listMembers (obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
    }
}

// get members for current scope
listMembers(this);
```

This can get a little hairy if you're in the global scope (eg. the `window` object). It will also return built-in and prototypical methods. You can curb this by:

1. Using `propertyIsEnumerable()` or `hasOwnProperty()`
2. Attempting to `delete` the property (`true` mostly means user-created, `false` means built-in, though this can be erratic)
3. Stripping members you know you don't want through some other filtering array

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Consider: `function foo(){ var bar = 42; listMembers(this); }` — in this case, `this` is not at all related to the definition of `bar`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the source of the current function scope, like this:

```
arguments.callee.toString()
```

So I suppose you could parse that string, matching things like "var " and "function ", matching from then until ";" or "}"

But that would be a very very messy, brute-force approach!  If you really need to get this kind of information, you'd be better off not creating variables at all -- define every value and function as an object property, then you can simply iterate through them with for(key in obj)

Comment: This will return the source code of the calling function, but it won't return the namespace.