# Print all variables?

Tags: javascript

I want to do a function that can be used a lot in debugging that print all variables with their values. It would alert:
x=3
y=2

The function would be like that :
**Exemple :**

```
var text='';
for(var a=0;a<allVariables;a++)
{
    text+=nameOfVariable + " = " + valueOfVariable + "/n";
}
alert(text);
```

Comment: Use console.log for debugging.

Comment: In addition to console.log, I highly recommend using the dev tools available for browsers. Chrome has one built-in (F12), and FireFox has FireBug extension/plugin

Comment: @racar You probably want to find out what browser op is using before you suggest that. Also, why NOT use alert if that's what you prefer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting All Variables In Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope)

Answer (score 16):

This will probably do what you're looking for:

```
console.dir(window);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use console methods, it's the best for debugging. Quite all modern browsers have the console, and you can use better debugging tools like firebug for firefox. Then a simple `console.log(allVariables)` and it is all shown in the console.

Comment: You mean, all variables of the page ? They are all stored in the `window` object in webbrowsers and in the `global` object in node.js. So you just have to do `console.log(window)` to see all declared variables. Otherwise you can declare allVariables: `allVariables={x:3, y:2}; console.log(allVariables);`

Answer (score 1):

It can be difficult to determine what "all the variables" are if you use anything global.  By default, global variables all fall under the `window` scope.  So you could loop over all values in `window`, but that would give you *everything else* as well.

If you put everything inside of a namespace, you can be more explicit about it.

```
var MyVariables = {
};

MyVariables.foo = 1;
MyVariables.hello = 'world';

for(var name in MyVariables){
    console.log(name, MyVariables[name]);
}
```

Also check out the dev tools available on your browser.  I personally would recommend Chrome Dev tools (builtin, F12), or FireBug in FireFox.  IE does have some built-ins as well.

Comment: how do i access to that window scope (i could do a regex to have the variables only)

Comment: @user1342369 it's just `window`.  e.g. `window.foo`