# get all defined variables in current scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm parsing a website which contains stuff like

```
hmapId[7]='42500000000626135';
hmapStartInterv[7]='750';
hmapEndInterv[7]='846';
hmapUrlInterv[7]='some url';
hmapNameInterv[7]="some name"
hmapRoleInterv[7]='some role';
```

My plan is to write that into a `.js` file and execute it with node js. After that I want to have some lines of code giving me all variables defined before as JSON to use the data in some other program. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean something like `get_defined_vars` in php, I guess thats not possible in javascript.

Comment: It's not possible:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope

You can parse it with regex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the current scope, it's not possible (AFAIK), for the global scope you have the `global`object in node.js (`window` in navigator embedded js engines), which get the global variables properties:

```
// on global scope, with x not defined as a "var"
x=25
console.info(global['x']===x) // --> writes down 'true'
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it for my case, global scope is sufficient :)

Comment: Be aware that the global object contains Everything that's global, even Funtion, Object, other modules, etc.,,