# How to query javascript's object space

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

JavaScript creates a bunch of objects in memory. Even "classes" are really just prototype objects in JavaScript.

I want to create a list of all of the objects currently instantiated on a page. I realize this might include JavaScript basic objects like `String.prototype` and `Number.prototype`. I think that's great!

Bonus points for also telling me how to query JavaScript's object space more specifically. Perhaps, say, find all objects currently in memory with a property key matching "name".

Comment: `for (var prop in window) { ... }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting All Variables In Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope)