# Enumerate all properties of current scope in JS

Tags: javascript, scope

Is it possible to create a function `enumerateScope()` that lists all properties (keys) of the current scope?

```
<script>
var a = "foo";
enumerateScope(); //all properties of global window object including 'a'
</script>
```

this is pretty easy, but what about this?

```
<script>
(function(){
   var b = "bar";
   enumerateScope(); //either only 'b' or all properties of global window object including 'b'
})();
</script>
```

The last case is what I am interested in. I **don't** want to change any code inside the anonymous / closure scope just like

```
(function(scope){scope.b = "bar";})(window);
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting All Variables In Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this isn't *impossible* in the strict sense, consider

```
bindings = function() {
    var v = String(bindings.caller).match(/\w+/g).join(" ");
    return "('"+v+"'.split(' ').reduce(function($1,$2){try{$1[$2]=eval($2)}finally{return $1}},{}))";
}


vars = (function(){
    var b = "bar";
    var foo = "quux";
    return eval(bindings())
})();

console.log(vars) 
//{
// "b": "bar",
// "foo": "quux"
//}
```

but I wouldn't call it *practical* in most cases, except, maybe, for debugging purposes.

Comment: It doesn't look like it would work for non-primitives, also you are parsing javascript with the regex `\w+` which hardly looks like it would work anything but something you carefully crafted.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it's not possible. Variable declarations create bindings to the current execution context's environment record, which is not something you have access to.

See ["Declaration Binding Instantiation"](http://es5.github.io/#x10.5) in the spec for the details.

See also the section on [execution context](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3) (emphasis added):

> An execution context is purely a specification mechanism and need not correspond to any particular artefact of an ECMAScript implementation. **It is impossible for an ECMAScript program to access an execution context**.