# Access declared variables via `this` in non-global scopes

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var x = 16;
console.log(this["x"]); // 16
```

I'm ok with this, but:

```
(function () {
  var y = 16;
  console.log(this["y"]); // undefined
}());
```

Why we cant access variables via `this` ?!

I know it's possibe when we assign values, for example:

```
(function () {
  x = 16; // will assigned as `this["x"] = 16`
  console.log(x); // 16;
}());
```

What's `var` problem with non-global scopes?!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Or do you just want to know why this works like this?

Comment: @oliverspies Just want to know why this works like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably read up on how [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) works.

Declaring a variable in a local scope using `var x = 16` is not the same as doing `this.x = 16`.  The former example is just a local variable, the latter affects the local context.

Your example:

```
(function () {
  var y = 16;
  console.log(this["y"]); // undefined
}());
```

That sets a local variable called `y`, but then looks for `y` as defined in the current context, probably `window.y`.  Since the local variable `y` is not the same as `window.y`, you get undefined.

Comment: @mr-llama Why `window.y` ?! i thought `this` is pointing to defined scope using IIFE not `window`, so what's can access all declared variables using `var` in IIFE scope?!

Comment: @rf7 - [Give it a shot.](https://jsfiddle.net/045nspx6/)  Check your browser's console for the results.

Comment: @mr-llama Oops! it seems `this` is referring to the `window`, but IIFE is a new scope; is there any way to see all of declared variables (with `var`) inside new scope just like `console.log(this);` for `window`?!

Comment: @rf7 - [Nope](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2051693/477563), not programmatically at least. :(