# Know every function on scope

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a function main that has several inner functions like this:

```
function main_f (params) {
    function do_this () {
        // do this...
    }
    function do_that () {
        do_this(); // working
        main_f.parse_stuff(); // not working
        parse_stuff(); // not working
    }
    do_that();
    main_f.parse_stuff = function(){
        console.log("success");
    }
}
function second_f () {
    main_f.parse_stuff(); //working
}
```

I was expecting that `main_f.parse_stuff()` would work inside `do_that`, but that is not the case. My questions are:

**-Is it posible to call that method from inside `main_f` ? how?**

EDIT: Execute do_that after parse_stuff is written.

**-Why can't I call `parse_stuff` from `main_f`?**

EDIT: I just realised that the function doesn't read on compilation time, but execution time, therefore it is not visible when do_that is called.

**-How can I know every function on scope?**

Comment: I found what was wrong, I think. As main_f doesn't read before execution, the call was being made before the function load. Anyway, I'd like to know how to get the functions available in that scope, if possible.ç

Comment: Your remaining question is simple, you can't iterate over the scope to see what's inside.

Comment: Why is it not possible?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2051693/1338292) will help you on the why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible by programation but you can do it with the debugger. Just insert a break point on that scope and you can check everything that is global, local and in the closure.

I checked this with chrome dev-tools.