# Get list of closure variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Are there any ability to get closure variables list (Ok, maybe all scope variables) in JavaScript?

Sample:

```
function factory(){
    var _secret = "Some secret";
    return function(code){
        // How to get parent function variables names here? 
        // ...
    }
}

var inside = factory();

inside();
```

Comment: nope, this impossibly.

Comment: _// How to get parent function variables names here?_ - you can use `_secret` direct. you want something else?

Comment: @Grundy I need "get closure variables list (Ok, maybe all scope variables)". I have no idea which closure variables I have.

Comment: In this case - see comment above - in provided code this impossibly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see them is using `console.dir` to get all the scopes including closures scopes and their variables list. Example:

```
function factory(){
    var _secret = "Some secret";
    var i = 0;
    return function(){
        i++;    
        return _secret + i;
    }
}

var inside = factory();
inside(); // "Some secret1"
inside(); // "Some secret2"
console.dir(inside); // It shows you all variables in [[Scopes]] > Closure
```

Image of how you would see the console:

[image: console.dir output]

It works in Chromium based browsers.

Edit:
Related answer with nested scopes in related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66896639/2391782

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is for debugging purposes, you can try parsing the function body and evaluating identifiers found:

```js
function getvars(fn, _eval) {
    var words = String(fn).replace(/".*?"|'.*?'/g, '').match(/\b[_A-Za-z]\w*/g),
        ret = {}
    words.forEach(function(w) {
        try { ret[w] = _eval(w) } catch (e) {};
    });
    return ret;
}

function factory() {
    var _secret = "Some secret";
    var _other = "Other secret";

    return function(code){
        var vars = getvars(factory, _ => eval(_));
        return vars;
    }
}


vars = factory()();
document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(vars,0,3));
```

Needless to say, this is an extremely naive way to deal with code, so handle it with care.

Comment: I like this solution. I am newbie. Could please give some information about following expression?: _ => eval(_)

Comment: In my situation I have my js code running in closure of other lib function (my code will be evaluated)  so your solution looks good (Yes i need this just for debugging). Main issue is to find the name of this outer function.

Comment: @blindProgrammer this is ES6 arrow functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @blindProgrammer:  we need to pass "eval" to `getvars` so that it will be aware of the local bindings. Since `eval` is special, we can't pass it directly, and have to wrap it in a function - in this case as a "fat arrow" one.

Answer (score 1):

There's no comprehensive way to get a list of all variables in scope. You could enumerate over the `this` object, but that will still only give you a list of the *enumerable* objects on `this`, and even at that there will still be things like function arguments that aren't on `this`.

So no, this cannot be done. Also check out this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope).

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible.
ECMAScript specification doesn't expose [Enviroment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-environment-records) objects to end user anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Since the primary concept of a closure is scope, and vars inside a closure are private, there can be no way to achieve this without exposing them somehow, like via a method.

What are you really trying to achieve?