# Getting the nth names of vars in scope

Tags: javascript

I have a few variables set up like this:

```
var foo, bar, fizz, buzz, hello, world;
```

Now I want to find out how to get those names as a collection of some sort. I am trying to get them since I want to push them in an array as a string.

I hope it doesnt require eval or something hacky. Is what I am trying to do possible?

I just need to know how to get the names, I prefer to solve the rest myself.

**Edit:** About the answer from the linked duplicate, I dont really get what he is doing there as I get everything other than names. Ive read it before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting All Variables In Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use a bad solution to solve your problem. What do you want to achieve with these variable names?

Comment: Sounds like a typical [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @sabithpocker you are right. Thank you for making me aware of this

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be better if you have used javascript object here and put variables in it as properties:

```
var obj = {foo:'', bar:'', fizz:''};
```

This way you can access both name of the property and its value:

```
obj.foo
for(key in obj) {
  alert(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
}
```

Comment: What other way is there? I know thats possible and I hope I could avoid using json for that

Comment: @Asperger Its not JSON, its a Javascript Object.

Comment: @sabithpocker - you are correct, edited.
Asperger why would you avoid it? Can you give us a bit more context what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of variables by Object.keys() method, but it returns all variables that object has:

```
var ar = Object.keys(this);
console.log(ar);
```