# Is there a way to look at all of the variables available to me in the given scope, or to look at different scopes using console.log?

Tags: javascript, debugging, graph, console.log

A little background: I'm writing a graph and am trying to put together a removeEdge method on the graph prototype with two arguments, the two nodes that will be losing their connection. So far, I've been able to make this a one-way severance by using 'this', so I was wondering how to look for the right variable to alter? console.log(window) is a nightmare of complexity so I very much doubt it's the right option for this. Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting All Variables In Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope)

Answer (score 0):

You can view all the variables in scope while paused in execution at a breakpoint. Once you are paused at the breakpoint, you can view all the variables you have in scope in the "scope" panel in the "sources" tab. You can also access these variables in the console.

You may benefit from reading about breakpoints and viewing variables in scope in this [blog article](http://shaynelinhart.com) I recently wrote about DevTools.